# Convert RIS or NBIB or JSON to bibtex?

Tags: bibtex, json

[This](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC181008/) article is not in Google Scholar, and they offer citations in RIS, NBIB, and JSON.

So the big question is, how can I convert this to bibtex?

Here is how it looks in JSON:

```json
{"source":"PMC","accessed":{"date-parts":[[2015,9,29]]},"id":"aiid:181008","title":"The Genome Sequence of <i>Yersinia pestis</i> Bacteriophage φA1122 Reveals an Intimate History with the Coliphage T3 and T7 Genomes","author":[{"family":"Garcia","given":"Emilio"},{"family":"Elliott","given":"Jeffrey M."},{"family":"Ramanculov","given":"Erlan"},{"family":"Chain","given":"Patrick S. G."},{"family":"Chu","given":"May C."},{"family":"Molineux","given":"Ian J."}],"container-title-short":"J Bacteriol","container-title":"Journal of Bacteriology","publisher":"American Society for Microbiology","ISSN":"0021-9193","issued":{"date-parts":[[2003,9]]},"page":"5248-5262","volume":"185","issue":"17","PMID":"12923098","PMCID":"PMC181008","DOI":"10.1128/JB.185.17.5248-5262.2003","type":"article-journal"}
```

or in pretty print:

```json
{
"DOI": "10.1128/JB.185.17.5248-5262.2003",
"ISSN": "0021-9193",
"PMCID": "PMC181008",
"PMID": "12923098",
"accessed": {
    "date-parts": [
        [
            2015,
            9,
            29
        ]
    ]
},
"author": [
    {
        "family": "Garcia",
        "given": "Emilio"
    },
    {
        "family": "Elliott",
        "given": "Jeffrey M."
    },
    {
        "family": "Ramanculov",
        "given": "Erlan"
    },
    {
        "family": "Chain",
        "given": "Patrick S. G."
    },
    {
        "family": "Chu",
        "given": "May C."
    },
    {
        "family": "Molineux",
        "given": "Ian J."
    }
],
"container-title": "Journal of Bacteriology",
"container-title-short": "J Bacteriol",
"id": "aiid:181008",
"issue": "17",
"issued": {
    "date-parts": [
        [
            2003,
            9
        ]
    ]
},
"page": "5248-5262",
"publisher": "American Society for Microbiology",
"source": "PMC",
"title": "The Genome Sequence of <i>Yersinia pestis</i> Bacteriophage \u03c6A1122 Reveals an Intimate History with the Coliphage T3 and T7 Genomes",
"type": "article-journal",
"volume": "185"
}
```

Comment: If it isn't in Google Scholar, why does it matter what they offer? Presumably 'they` does not refer to 'Google Scholar', but that's the obvious interpretation.

Comment: Keep in mind that these software-generated data sometimes have their pitfalls https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/386053/35864

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You sure about that?

```
@article{garcia2003genome,
  title={The genome sequence of Yersinia pestis bacteriophage $\varphi$A1122 reveals an intimate history with the coliphage T3 and T7 genomes},
  author={Garcia, Emilio and Elliott, Jeffrey M and Ramanculov, Erlan and Chain, Patrick SG and Chu, May C and Molineux, Ian J},
  journal={Journal of bacteriology},
  volume={185},
  number={17},
  pages={5248--5262},
  year={2003},
  publisher={Am Soc Microbiol}
}
```

Comment: Can I ask what you searched for? I have really spend a lot of time on this.

Comment: I put the full title of the article into google scholar search box

Comment: On another note, don't overcomplicate things, if something cannot be found, just write the entry by hand, either in a notepad, or using Jabref or some other Bibtex Manager -- you don't need a converter unless you had like 100+ in a particular format and it would save time over doing it manually...

Comment: Ok, I feel really stupid now. I have really tried this... Anyway thanks a lot =)

Comment: No worries, all good.

Answer (score 18):

To convert from RIS to BibTeX, I use this as part of a shell script:

```
ris2xml <filename>.ris | xml2bib -b > <filename>.bib
```

RIS is therefore my second choice of download format and quite handy since several places don't provide BibTeX but do provide RIS export.

Both `ris2xml` and `xml2bib` are provided by [bibutils](http://ctan.org/pkg/bibutils).

If you use a GNU/Linux distro, check for a package before resorting to a direct CTAN download as that will be easier to maintain in most cases.

For Arch Linux, there's a `PKGBUILD` in AUR, for example, and I think Fedora provides a package, as well.

Comment: 'If you use a *frequently-updated* GNU/Linux distro' -- if you run on Ubuntu LTS versions or some other stable builds everything TeX-related get hopelessly out of date.

Comment: @ChrisH Well, LTS is aimed at stability. Besides, `bibutils` has not changed in quite some time, so it is extremely unlikely that using an LTS distro's package will get you anything different from a direct download. (But should there be an update, of course you wouldn't then get it for some time.)

Comment: Yes, I like stability in my OS.  Not necessarily in the application software though.  And I did a lot of work last year under Ubuntu 12.04 LTS (not wanting to update in the middle of writing my thesis).  It had TeX live 20**09**.

Comment: @ChrisH `bibutils` hasn't been touched on CTAN since 2008.

Answer (score 8):

Tool [doi2bib](https://www.doi2bib.org/) has moto "give us a DOI and we will do our best to get you the BibTeX entry" and it works for DOI specified in given json.

Comment: This is amazing!

Answer (score 2):

To complement the other answers, there are also some online tools to do that. If you don't intend to convert many references it's probably a good option.

From a Google search, this "[Online ris2bib](https://www.bruot.org/ris2bib/)" and that "[Online Web of Science to bibTeX](http://www.lagom.nl/latex/i2b/online.html)" seem quite popular.

For more than a few conversions, I find Jabref very useful.

**EDIT**

With the first tool, it is actually possible to input text that is a concatenation of several RIS entries. So it might be good for bulk conversion after all...

Comment: Welcome! Please label your links more informatively. If those links die, searching the internet for 'this one' or 'that one' is unlikely to return much of use.

Comment: JabRef is indeed a life saver!

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of completeness you can of course write a converter to convert from JSON to BibTeX. The following snippet (based on code from stackoverflow) shows, that just a few lines of e.g. Python code are required to get to information from this JSON object.

```python
# http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20199126/reading-a-json-file-using-python
import json
import codecs

with codecs.open("bibtex.json", "r", "utf-8") as jsonfile:
    py_object = json.load(jsonfile)
    jsonfile.close()
    print(py_object['publisher'])
```

Answer (score 1):

A R answer:

```bash
# system terminal
pip install citepy
citepy pandas > pandas.json #(not in python)
```

```R
# R
library(jsonlite)
#install.packages("RefManageR")
library(RefManageR)

pan<-fromJSON("pandas.json")
pan$bibtype<-"Misc"
rownames(pan)<-"pandas2021"
panbib<-as.BibEntry(pan)
WriteBib(panbib,"pandas.bib")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can download medley desktop, import your format source and then select studies and export to .bib format. Simple and useful.