# Software-generated bibliographic entries: common errors and other mistakes to check before use

Tags: bibliographies

**Background Story:** 
While answering bibliography questions on this site, I often come across incorrect bibliography entries - most of the time they were automatically generated by

- Google Scholar
- Mendeley
- ADS
- Journal websites
- ...

**Question:**

What are notorious problems of automatically generated bib entries? Which things to check before using?

To get a useful sorting please vote for the problems you often encounter / find most important (at the moment all answers are Community Wiki so it does not affect the reputation of the users).

**Alphabetic list of topics:**

- [Abstract or other extraneous data](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/386616/36296)
- [Acronyms in titles](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/386056/36296)
- [archivePrefix](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/386067/36296)
- [Author list](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/386063/36296)
- [Bracing](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/430496/36296)
- [Bracing the family names](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/415148/36296)
- [Content](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/386075/36296)
- [Corporate authors](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/386066/36296)
- [Custom macros/strings](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/439339/36296)
- [Escaping special characters](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/469377/36296)
- [HTML (including character codes)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/386386/36296)
- [Incorrect entry type](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/386054/36296)
- [Month](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/386058/36296)
- [Non-ASCII characters](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/386061/36296)
- [Surnames that consist of more than one word](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/386081/36296)
- [Ranges](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/386062/36296)
- [Uppercase letters](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/386068/36296)
- [URL](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/386073/36296)
- [year vs. date](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/386238/36296)

Comment: @ShreevatsaR You have to ask Mico :)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

## Author list

Some common problems:

- Are the authors' names spelled correctly? Are all accents correct? Are all language specific characters correct, i.e. ñ in Spanish, å in Nordic languages, č in Czech, and so on? Is the capitalisation correct (see also https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/386066/36296 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/386068/36296) ?
- Confusion between first and second names
- Confusion between what's the surname component and the given-names component. E.g., for the author named "Marco Del Negro", the author field should be written either as `author = "Del Negro, Marco"` or `author = "Marco {Del Negro}"`.
- name parts like `van`, `von`, `de`, `junior`, `senior` are placed incorrectly
- For entries with two or more authors, failure to use the keyword `and` as the separator between names. For instance, the following field uses commas inappropriately:

  ```
  author = {{Sudipto Bhattacharya, CAE Goodhart, Dimitrios Tsomocos}, 
             Alexandros Vardoulakis},
  ```

  It should be

  ```
  author = {Sudipto Bhattacharya and C. A. E. Goodhart and 
            Dimitrios Tsomocos and Alexandros Vardoulakis},
  ```
- be consistent with spacing between multiple initials, e.g. sometimes they are exported as `Smith, M.~L.` while others do `Smith, M.L.`, or `Smith, M. L.`.

  - Most well-written BibTeX styles and `biblatex` treat `Smith, M. L.` and `Smith, M.~L.` alike, so there is rarely something to be won using `~` between name initials. `Smith, M.L.` on the other hand will not be recognised as a name with two first name initials, but rather as only one very unusual first name "M.L.", which may be abbreviated to "M.".

Comment: @Miguel Thanks for your input! I think it is better to merged your information with the first point. Can you please have a look at my edit if this reflects your point well enough? Please feel free to roll back if you don't like it.

Comment: Note though that sometimes the name as written on the work itself might be missing diacritics, so in that case it is debatable whether or not to include them. Always check back with the work you cited as well as your previous knowledge.

Comment: There are also plenty of cases where initials are in the form `M. L.` and break across lines, or use a non-breaking space character.

Comment: Braces around names can generate inconveniencies: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/414685/105447. (Not sure it should be included, for I don't really know the culprit there, but I leave it here in the comments for reference).

Comment: @gusbrs Thanks for the link! I'll wait a bit before I'll add this to the list as for me this looks more like a bug in biber/biblatex.

Comment: @samcarter, agreed. But egreg is quite clear that this is conceptually wrong and can tamper with sorting, if nothing else. Still, that this should break compilation, does seem to be a bug, imho.

Comment: @gusbrs I read the answer and acknowledge that without braces is certainly the cleanest way to give the names, however biblatex also accepts the syntax `author = "Donald Duck"` -- for this {} have to be allowed around the names parts in case they contain spaces etc.

Comment: Sometimes you will see a name "Smith, M" with no period at the end. The given name is almost certainly not just "M", this is an abbreviation - and then there should be a period. If you then use a style that uses full first names, there will again not be a period. This is probably the smallest possible nitpick...

Answer (score 24):

## Failure to treat corporate-author cases properly in `author` and `editor` fields

Consider the following three author fields:

```
author = {National Aeronautics and Space Administration},
author = {Bureau of Labor Statistics},
author = {International Monetary Fund},
```

All three are instances of "corporate" authors. The correct way to write them is

```
author = {{National Aeronautics and Space Administration}},
author = {{Bureau of Labor Statistics}},
author = {{International Monetary Fund}},
```

Without this special treatment, the first author field will be parsed as having *two separate authors* -- recall that `and` is a keyword in `author` and `editor` fields! -- called "National Aeronautics" and "Space Administration", respectively. The second author will be parsed as having "of" as the "von component" and hence a two-component surname ("Labor Statistics") and a single given name ("Bureau"). The third author would be parsed as having surname "Fund" and given names "International" and "Monetary"! Moreover, if the bibliographic entries are sorted alphabetically, the first entry would be sorted under "A" for "Aeronautics", the second under "L" for "Labor Statistics", and the third under "F" for "Fund". The correct letters would, of course, be "N", "B", and "I", respectively.

By encasing the entire name in an additional pair of curly braces, BibTeX and biber are led to believe that the authors' names have just one component (the surname component).

---

In many automatic data bases, corporate authors are already wrongly divided in first and last name parts, so pay attention to any stray letters. [An example](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/cgi-bin/nph-bib_query?bibcode=2017arXiv170907997C&data_type=BIBTEX&db_key=PRE&nocookieset=1):

```
    author = {{Cherenkov Telescope Array Consortium}, T. and [...] and et al.},
```

where the "The" from the original author list was mistakenly interpreted as first name and abbreviated.

Answer (score 21):

## Month

The syntax for month is often incorrectly exported as `month = {mar}`. This should be changed to

- `month = mar` (no braces!) or `month = {3}` in case you are using **BibTeX**
- **`biblatex`**'s Biber backend is less demanding and "only" issues a warning with this syntax, nevertheless you should change it to `month = {3}` or **better `date = {1990-03}`** instead of year and month.

(Example taken from [How can I find a bibtex entry for an article?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/375545/how-can-i-find-a-bibtex-entry-for-an-article/375550#comment929440_375549) )

Comment: Interestingly even `month = {mar}` comes out OK with Biber, but there is a warning about sorting. (I'm not sure if maybe the warning is incorrect.) Biber would also accept `month = mar` without further complaints. But BibTeX really can't take `month = {mar}`.

Comment: @moewe Thanks a lot for your feedback. I tried to incorporate your information into the answer, could you please check if it is given correctly and edit as you find necessary?

Comment: @samcarter, wouldn't it be a good idea to generalize for "Date" issues? For example, most auto-generated entries come with the year, in the `year` field, while if you are using `biblatex` the `date` field is recommended. True, this wouldn't result in an error, but AFAIK the `date` will get a more general treatment, for unspecified dates and so on, while `year` won't. Perhaps there are other differences there, this is one I could think of.

Comment: @gusbrs Please feel free to amend this "community wiki" answer.

Comment: @samcarter, I thought of it, but as it would redirect the original scope of the answer and I'm not that sure of the relevance of my point, I thought (and think) it would be best done by someone with more experience...

Comment: @gusbrs How about writing a new answer about the date issue? I am sure some of the bibliography experts read our answers to this questions and will comment in case they disagree with your point?

Answer (score 21):

## Failure to treat URL strings properly

URL strings frequently are quite long, and they often contain characters -- such as `&`, `#`, `$`, `%` and `_` -- that have special meanings when parsed by TeX. URL strings should either be encased in a `\url{...}` wrapper (be sure to load the `url` and/or `hyperref` packages!) or placed in a field called `url`.

Almost all styles that support a dedicated `url` field accept the URL without additional markup and can interface with the `url`/`hyperref` package. URLs in the `url` field should *not* be wrapped in a `\url{...}` call.

```
url = {\url{https://openreview.net/pdf?id=tV6oBfuyLTQ}},
```

is wrong and should be just

```
url = {https://openreview.net/pdf?id=tV6oBfuyLTQ},
```

Sometimes one sees machine-generated URL strings in which the TeX-special characters have been prefixed with `\` (backslash characters). A real-life example:

```
url = {http://digitalcommons.bard.edu/hm{\_}archive/180},
```

This is awful. Change it to

```
url = {http://digitalcommons.bard.edu/hm_archive/180},
```

especially if you intend to make the URL string usable for your readers (which, obviously, you really should intend to do).

Some export tools put the URL into the `note` field, if you use a style that supports a dedicated `url` and `urldate` field (`biblatex` styles in general do that, `url` is also supported by some BibTeX styles), you should use those if possible.

Answer (score 17):

## Non-ASCII characters

This is something to be checked in basically every field. For example this title:

```
title={Towards a new research programme—Implications of [...]},
```

the insuspicious looking `—` will (for most setups?) cause an error, so replace it by `--`.

Another examples are ligatures like "fl" and "fi", spaces which just look like spaces and totally invisible characters (searching these can be really annoying!).

Comment: A nasty case I've spotted is ligatures like "fl" and "fi", which in a monospaced font with a "helpful" editor can fall back to looking *exactly* the same as two characters

Comment: @ChrisH Very good point! I added it to the answer - thank you!

Answer (score 16):

## Incorrect entry type

Is the entry type correct? Quite often, the entry type `@article` is used for entries that are not pieces published in journals. Rule of thumb: **If a given entry is lacking the field names `journal` and `volume`, it almost certainly shouldn't be an `@article`**. Especially if you use `biblatex` you might want to watch out for differences between `@book` and `@collection` as well as `@inbook` and `@incollection`.

### Examples

#### Papers only published on arXiv

[inspirehep](https://inspirehep.net/record/1637592/export/hx) exports the following entry as `@article`:

```
@article{Wegman:2017zui,
      author         = "Wegman, D.",
      title          = "{Deviations of exact neutrino textures using radiative
                        neutrino masses}",
      year           = "2017",
      eprint         = "1711.08004",
      archivePrefix  = "arXiv",
      primaryClass   = "hep-ph",
      SLACcitation   = "%%CITATION = ARXIV:1711.08004;%%"
}
```

while it seems that at the time I retrieved this entry (13 February 2018) the article was not (yet) published in a journal, thus `@online` would be more appropriate. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/415117/36296 for a more detailed explanation.

#### PhD theses

The PhD thesis available at http://elib.suub.uni-bremen.de/diss/docs/00010668.pdf is exported by Google Scholar as

```
@article{lorenz2007repeated,
  title={Repeated averaging and bounded confidence-modeling,
         analysis and simulation of continuous opinion dynamics},
  author={Lorenz, Von Jan},
  year={2007},
  publisher={Citeseer}
}
```

and [by CiteSeerX as](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.630.607)

```
@TECHREPORT{Lorenz07repeatedaveraging,
    author = {Von Jan Lorenz},
    title = {Repeated Averaging and Bounded Confidence -
             Modeling, Analysis and Simulation of Continuous Opinion Dynamics},
    institution = {},
    year = {2007}
}
```

Note the incorrect name fields `author = {Von Jan Lorenz},` and `author={Lorenz, Von Jan},`. The author is called *Jan Lorenz*, presumably the "von" was added because the title page has "*Repeated Averaging and Bounded Confidence: Modeling, Analysis and Simulation of Continuous Opinion Dynamics* von Jan Lorenz", here "von" is the German for "by".

Furthermore, Google Scholar collapses CiteSeerX's separator between title and subtitle (`␣-␣`, where `␣` is a space), into `-` making it appear that the thesis is about `bounded confidence-modeling`.

Lastly, it is a bit of a stretch to list CiteSeer as the `publisher` here. Traditionally `@article` entries don't show a publisher anyway, so there is little point in including it, but CiteSeer did most certainly not publish the original thesis.

For most BibTeX styles the correct entry would probably be

```
@phdthesis{lorenz,
  author = {Jan Lorenz},
  title  = {Repeated Averaging and Bounded Confidence:
            Modeling, Analysis and Simulation of Continuous Opinion Dynamics},
  school = {Universität Bremen},
  year   = {2007},
}
```

and for `biblatex` it would be

```
@phdthesis{lorenz,
  author      = {Jan Lorenz},
  title       = {Repeated Averaging and Bounded Confidence},
  subtitle    = {Modeling, Analysis and Simulation of Continuous Opinion Dynamics},
  institution = {Universität Bremen},
  date        = {2007-02},
  url         = {http://elib.suub.uni-bremen.de/diss/docs/00010668.pdf},
}
```

This example can be found in [Incomplete references in Revtex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/532626/35864).

Comment: @Mico Thanks a lot for your edit! I always struggle with the terminology for bibliography things :)

Comment: A real case example: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/415115/105447

Comment: @gusbrs Thanks for the link. I tried to include this information in the answer.

Answer (score 16):

## Failure to treat surnames that consist of more than one word.

(This point is related to [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/386063/5001).)

Consider the names "Antonio P. Garcia Pascual", "Marco Del Negro", "John Le Carré", "Helena Bonham Carter", and "Kristin Scott Thomas". What do they have in common? In all cases, the surnames have two components; hence, "Garcia", "Del", "Le", Bonham", and "Scott" are *not* middle names subject to truncation (or outright omission), and the authors should be sorted under "G", "D", "L", "B", and "S", respectively.

A real-life example: There is a well-known article (at least among international economists...) authored by Yin-Wong Cheung, Menzie Chinn, and Antonio Garcia Pascual. A citation call-out that shows all three names should be written as `Cheung, Chinn, and Garcia Pascual`, *not* as `Cheung, Chinn, and Pascual`.

Enter the authors' names as `Garcia Pascual, Antonio P.`, `Del Negro, Marco`, etc. to ensure that they'll get parsed correctly.

Answer (score 14):

## Ranges

for example for pages numbers, are often handled inconsistently. Sometimes they are exported as `pages={1--42}`, others give `pages={1-42}`.

There are arguments for both ways and it also depends on the used style (see [moewe's comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/386053/software-generated-bibliographic-entries-common-errors-and-other-mistakes-to-ch/386062?noredirect=1#comment1078520_386062) below), but at the very least be consistent.

Comment: As it turns out for BibTeX a single dash `1-42` is preferable. French typography for example apparently prefers a hyphen instead of an en-dash. Most styles do normalisation of ranges by adding a `-` to make it `--` if necessary. But no style deletes `-`s. So the normalisation from `1-42` to `1--42` can happen automatically, while `1--42` to `1-42` does not. Of course using `1-42` means you have to modify your style if it does not apply the normalisation.

Comment: For `biblatex` (with Biber) any consecutive number of dashes is replaced by `\bibrangedash` so the input format does not really matter. The LaTeX-side normalisation that is applied in postnote arguments also replaces `-` and `--` by `\bibrangedash`. So for `biblatex` it does not really matter whether you write `1-42` or `1--42`.

Answer (score 12):

## Acronyms in titles

Acronyms in titles are error prone. Some common problems are:

- additional spaces between the letters

  `NASA` becomes `N A S A`
- missing periods

  `H.E.S.S.` becomes `HESS`
- wrong capitalisation

  To fix the most common problem about capitalisation, enclose the respective letters in `{}`, e.g.

  ```
  title = "Pascal, {C}, {Java}: were they all conceived in {ETH}?"
  ```

  see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/10775/36296 for more information.

Comment: @moewe Would you mind if I would rename this answer to "Acronyms in titles"?

Comment: Not at all, I thought we might broaden the scope a bit since names and other things also need to be case-protected.

Comment: The dot/period issue is style dependent in some cases: https://www.thoughtco.com/abbreviation-for-united-states-1691023 The question is whether the `.bib` file should follow the style as applied in the work cited or in the current work.

Answer (score 12):

## Failure to use uppercase letters

Consider the field

```
title={John maynard keynes and other british economists},
```

The failure to write this as either `title={John Maynard Keynes and Other British Economists},` or, better still, `title={{John Maynard Keynes} and Other {British} Economists},` (to prevent lowercasing of proper nouns) is dreadful.

Similarly, the field

```
journal = {The economic journal}
```

really should be `journal = {The Economic Journal}`.

Comment: Even when they try they still often get chemistry in article titles wrong

Answer (score 12):

## `year` vs. `date`

Most auto-generated entries come with the year in the `year` field, which is probably the safest for it will work as expected in most, or probably all, scenarios.

However, if you are using `biblatex` the `date` field is recommended. Fortunately, most export tools only export a bare year and that will be treated in exactly the same way in `year` and `date` by `biblatex`/Biber.
So, this wouldn't result in an error or in undesired results, but the `date` will get a more general treatment, while `year` won't.

For example, for unspecified dates, ranges, full dates and EDTF support, we will need `date`. In particular, there is no such field as day (in fact it is actively searched for and deleted by Biber), so if you need day precision, date is a must.

Hence, depending on the degree of control you expect to have on date handling, if you are using `biblatex`, this might be a place to check and adjust.

Also, even if `year` is recognized by `biblatex` for compatibility reasons, the same might not be the case for equivalent constructions of other dates in the data model. For example, the use of `origyear` instead of `origdate` does fool `biblatex-chicago` in [biblatex-chicago does not print origyear with cmsdate=both](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/427120/105447).

Comment: Fortunately though, most export tools only export a bare year and that will be treated in exactly the same way in `year` and `date`. For ranges, full dates and EDTF support, however, we will need `date`. A last point is that there is no such field as `day` (in fact it is actively searched for and deleted by Biber), so if you need day precision, `date` is a must.

Comment: @moewe, thanks! I tried to incorporate your input to the answer. Please take a look if the changes are in accordance to what you meant. Also, if you notice something still amiss or any other improvements to be made, let me know, or please be welcome to edit directly.

Answer (score 11):

## The content of the information itself.

In my experience the reference information itself should be checked for accuracy. Missing relevant information (missing fields) or erroneous supplied information do happen, I'd say somewhat frequently.

Perhaps I'm biased in this last statement, because I rely heavily on "pre-digital era" material, but I always check... Anyway, even if less frequent in normal cases, it may be tricky, for (La)TeX/Bib(la)tex/Biber (whatever you are using) won't issue any warning or error messages for you, and the result will be much worse than a poorly formatted reference.

---

Case in point: As of today the authors exported by Google Books for *Introduction to Apache Flink* (O'Reilly, 2016) on https://books.google.de/books?id=g0RMDQAAQBAJ are

```
author={Friedman, E. and Ellen Friedman, M.D. and Tzoumas, K.},
```

A short look on the cover reveals that the correct list of authors would be

```
author={Friedman, Ellen and Tzoumas, Kostas},
```

See [Identify which ??? key is missing in bibtex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/454341/)

Now this obvious error in the author list where the first author is duplicated might be easy to spot, but other errors might not be as obvious.

Answer (score 8):

## Excessive bracing in title fields

The opposite of [failure to use uppercase letters](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/386068/35864), related also to [acronyms in titles](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/386056/35864) and [bracing the family name](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/415148/35864).

Some databases may apply double bracing or the functionally equivalent quote-brace combination to title fields

```
title = "{Sensitivity of the high altitude water Cherenkov detector
         to sources of multi-TeV gamma rays}",
```

or

```
title = {{Language Change: Progress or Decay?}},
```

This is the WYSIWYG approach to title casing and destroys the sentence casing function of both BibTeX and `biblatex`.

It is preferable to only protect words that must always be written with capital letters like acronyms, names, proper nouns, ... See also [BibTeX loses capitals when creating .bbl file](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10772/35864)

If you don't like the fact that your current bibliography style converts titles to sentence case that should be fixed by modifying the style so it does not apply sentence case any more or by switching to a different style altogether. Changing the `.bib` file is not the best option here (even if it might be the quickest).

## Excessive bracing in other fields

While it could be argued that excessive bracing in title fields is somewhat useful for a quick and dirty WYSIWYG approach, apparently certain providers (ISI Web of Science) go even further and brace all fields.

```
@Article{lloyd3,
  author      = {Lloyd, Alison C.},
  title       = {{The Regulation of Cell Size}},
  journal     = {{CELL}},
  year        = {{2013}},
  volume      = {{154}},
  number      = {{6}},
  pages       = {{1194-1205}},
  month       = {{SEP 12}},
  issn        = {{0092-8674}},
  abstract    = {{An adult animal consists of cells of vastly different size and activity,
   but the regulation of cell size remains poorly understood. Recent
   studies uncovering some of the signaling pathways important for
   size/growth control, together with the identification of diseases
   resulting from aberrations in these pathways, have renewed interest in
   this field. This Review will discuss our current understanding of how a
   cell sets its size, how it can adapt its size to a changing environment,
   and how these processes are relevant to human disease.}},
  doi         = {{10.1016/j.cell.2013.08.053}},
  groups      = {cell_cycle_paper},
  owner       = {nbecker},
  times-cited = {{78}},
  timestamp   = {2018.04.24},
  unique-id   = {{ISI:000324239300010}},
}
```

from https://github.com/JabRef/jabref/issues/3974

This can cause quite astonishing error messages as demonstrated in [harvard bibliography, improper alphabetic constant](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/444021/35864).

The JabRef developers have also met this particular problem and tried to contact Clarivate about it: https://twitter.com/JabRef_org/status/1012695298240442368, https://github.com/JabRef/jabref/issues/3974 ... not sure if they heard back

Answer (score 7):

## Missing `archivePrefix`

This is something I observed on ADS, not sure if it also affects other sources, but Eprints are sometimes exported without the field `archivePrefix = "arXiv"`. As a result of the missing prefix, the hyperlink to the preprint is build incorrectly and does not work.

One example is this paper: http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2003A%26A...410..389R

(my rough estimate: about 20% of ADS preprints are effected - this is however based on the sample of papers I use for my own work and may not be representative)

(see [Workaround for missing archivePrefix in bib entry](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/386078/36296) for a biblatex workaround)

Answer (score 7):

### HTML (including character codes)

It's common to find things like `<sub>2</sub>` or `&#x2082;` in chemical formulae and similar cases.

Answer (score 7):

### The abstract or other extraneous data

While this may be useful, it's also a lot of bulk in your bib file which makes searching tedious. It's also a significant source of errors if it contains anything other than plain text, as many of the other problems discussed here can occur. (I remove this field, either manually on import or with a regex in my editor)

Keywords fields can also be problematic. They sometimes seem to be auto-generated from the title without much care for maths or escaped special characters. (I also throw these away, sometimes replacing them with my own)

I've even seen a default option to export the bibliography entry *and all references*, which means many times the data to check. Again, one to be avoided unless you really want them.

Comment: Very good point about the abstract. One thing to note here is that `biblatex` with Biber is a lot more fussy about these things than traditional BibTeX. Unescaped special characters in `abstract` fields regularly cause problems for `biblatex` users - and because the abstract normally does not appear in the bibliography that can leave people confused.

Answer (score 5):

## Bracing the family names

With [ADS](http://adsabs.harvard.edu) the family names are incorrectly braced.

```
@ARTICLE{2013APh....50...26A,
  author = {{Abeysekara}, A.~U. and {Alfaro}, R. and {Alvarez}, C. and {{\'A}lvarez}, J.~D. and
    {Tollefson}, K. and {Torres}, I. and {Ukwatta}, T.~N. and {Villase{\~n}or}, L. and
    {Weisgarber}, T. and {Westerhoff}, S. and {Wisher}, I.~G. and
    {Wood}, J. and {Yodh}, G.~B. and {Younk}, P.~W. and {Zaborov}, D. and
    {Zepeda}, A. and {Zhou}, H.},
  title = "{Sensitivity of the high altitude water Cherenkov detector to sources of multi-TeV gamma rays}",
  journal = {Astroparticle Physics},
  archivePrefix = "arXiv",
  eprint = {1306.5800},
  primaryClass = "astro-ph.HE",
  keywords = {TeV gamma-ray astronomy, Water cherenkov, Cosmic ray},
    year = 2013,
  month = dec,
  volume = 50,
  pages = {26-32},
  doi = {10.1016/j.astropartphys.2013.08.002},
  adsurl = {http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2013APh....50...26A},
  adsnote = {Provided by the SAO/NASA Astrophysics Data System}
}
```

(also the `~` tokens are wrong). In this case, the name

```
{{\'A}lvarez}
```

will cause a bbl file prepared with Biber to fail because of unmatched braces. The braces around the family names are bad under several other respects (sorting, mainly).

See [! Paragraph ended before \name was complete](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/414685/paragraph-ended-before-name-was-complete) for reference.

The issue is known to the developers of Biber, see [issue report here](https://github.com/plk/biber/issues/210),  and the erroneous input should no more raise errors. The braces remain wrong nonetheless.

Comment: +1 of course. But I think it is worth mentioning that the issue was reported and the next version of biber (2.11) should no longer result in unmatched braces and thus will not break compilation. (https://github.com/plk/biber/issues/210)

Answer (score 5):

## Custom macros/strings

The [ADS](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/) database uses custom macros for certain field values.

For common journals, a `.bib` entry downloaded from ADS will not contain

```
journal = {Monthly Notices of the Royal Astronomical Society},
```

or

```
journal = {MNRAS},
```

instead it will deliver a `.bib` file with

```
 journal = {\mnras},
```

For example [2018MNRAS.478.5556A](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2018MNRAS.478.5556A) [is exported as](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/cgi-bin/nph-bib_query?bibcode=2018MNRAS.478.5556A&data_type=BIBTEX&db_key=AST&nocookieset=1)

```
@ARTICLE{2018MNRAS.478.5556A,
   author = {{Alger}, M.~J. and {Banfield}, J.~K. and {Ong}, C.~S. and {Rudnick}, L. and 
    {Wong}, O.~I. and {Wolf}, C. and {Andernach}, H. and {Norris}, R.~P. and 
    {Shabala}, S.~S.},
    title = "{Radio Galaxy Zoo: machine learning for radio source host galaxy cross-identification}",
  journal = {\mnras},
archivePrefix = "arXiv",
   eprint = {1805.05540},
 primaryClass = "astro-ph.IM",
 keywords = {methods: statistical, techniques: miscellaneous, galaxies: active, infrared: galaxies, radio continuum: galaxies},
     year = 2018,
    month = aug,
   volume = 478,
    pages = {5556-5572},
      doi = {10.1093/mnras/sty1308},
   adsurl = {http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2018MNRAS.478.5556A},
  adsnote = {Provided by the SAO/NASA Astrophysics Data System}
}
```

In order to use this entry properly the macro `\mnras` must be defined in your document and it must give the correct replacement text.

The [ADS FAQ](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs_doc/faq.html#bibtex) and [the ADS BibTeX guide](http://ads.harvard.edu/pubs/bibtex/) list several options to get the journal macros to work. See also [Undefined control sequence BibTex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/366618/35864).

---

A related phenomenon is the IEEE journal abbreviation database ([short journal names in `IEEEabrv.bib`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/IEEEtran/bibtex/IEEEabrv.bib) and [full names in `IEEEfull.bib`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/IEEEtran/bibtex/IEEEfull.bib)). I could not find a database that provides its `.bib` entries using these journal strings, but who knows...

And entry making use of these journal strings would look like

```
@ARTICLE{5937283,
  author  = {P. Zhan and K. Yu and A. L. Swindlehurst},
  journal = IEEE_J_AES,
  title   = {Wireless Relay Communications with Unmanned Aerial Vehicles: Performance and Optimization},
  year    = {2011},
  month   = jul,
  volume  = {47},
  number  = {3},
  pages   = {2068-2085},
  doi     = {10.1109/TAES.2011.5937283},
}
```

In order to use this entry successfully in your document you would have to load either or `IEEEabrv.bib` or `IEEEfull.bib`.

Answer (score 5):

## Failure to escape special characters properly

Related to [Non-ASCII characters](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/386061/35864), [HTML (including character codes)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/386386/35864) and in a way the opposite of [Failure to treat URL strings properly](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/386073/35864).

Characters that have special meaning for TeX like `%`, `_`, `#`, ... must usually be escaped (see [Escape character in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/34580/35864)). There is an exception to this rule: Characters with special meaning need not be and indeed *should not* be escaped when they are used in verbatim fields like `url`, `doi` and `eprint` (cf. [Failure to treat URL strings properly](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/386073/35864)).

With BibTeX an error will only be raised when a field with problematic contents is actually printed (if you don't escape your `%`s it might even happen that no error is produced, but parts of the expected output might be missing). With `biblatex` an error will be raised even if the field is not printed. That error will occur directly when the `.bbl` file is read at `\begin{document}`.

---

A common example is the `abstract` field. Usually people don't notice malformed abstract contents when they use BibTeX, because hardly any styles print that field. But with `biblatex` the field is read even if it is not needed.

See for example [Changing from natbib to BibLaTex bibliography result in major errors](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/469361/35864). An unescaped `%` in the abstract of https://doi.org/10.1016/j.ddmec.2008.05.004 as exported by Elsevier

```
@article{BURT2007293,
title = "Inheritance of colorectal cancer",
journal = "Drug Discovery Today: Disease Mechanisms",
volume = "4",
number = "4",
pages = "293 - 300",
year = "2007",
issn = "1740-6765",
doi = "https://doi.org/10.1016/j.ddmec.2008.05.004",
url = "http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1740676508000369",
author = "Randall Burt",
abstract = "Inheritance is involved in up to one-third of colon cancer cases. Highly penetrant inherited syndromes account for approximately 3%, while more common, but less penetrant inherited factors play a role in the remainder. Approaches to recognizing each of these categories and syndromes, using genetic testing for diagnosis where indicated, and accomplishing proper cancer screening and surveillance will be outlined in this review."
}
```

would cause an

```
Runaway argument?
{Inheritance is involved in up to one third of colon cancer cases. Hi\ETC.
! File ended while scanning use of \field.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.36 \begin{document}
```

error with `biblatex`.

It would be necessary to escape the `%` as in

```
@article{burt,
  author   = {Randall Burt},
  title    = {Inheritance of colorectal cancer},
  journal  = {Drug Discovery Today: Disease Mechanisms},
  volume   = {4},
  number   = {4},
  pages    = {293-300},
  doi      = {10.1016/j.ddmec.2008.05.004},
  date     = {2007-12},
  abstract = {Inheritance is involved in up to one third of colon cancer
              cases. Highly penetrant inherited syndromes account for
              approximately 3\%, while more common, but less penetrant
              inherited factors play a role in the remainder.
              Approaches to recognizing each of these categories and
              syndromes, using genetic testing for diagnosis where
              indicated, and accomplishing proper cancer screening and
              surveillance will be outlined in this review.},
}
```

Note also the corrected `doi` field.

I concur with [The abstract or other extraneous data](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/386616/35864) that the `abstract` field usually does more harm than good and would recommend to just delete it.

Comment: Good point! Deleting the abstract field makes the bib file also much cleaner

Comment: @samcarter Absolutely, for most people the `abstract` field is just a waste of space and a possible gateway for errors to sneak in.

Comment: When I cleaned up my bib file, it was suddenly only half as long and much easier to navigate :)

Answer (score 4):

## Volume vs Number

For entries like `@book` or `@inbook`, BibTeX supports both a `VOLUME` and a `NUMBER` field (but not both). The former is intended for multi-volume books (*Collected works, vol. I*), whereas the latter is meant for numbers in a series (Lecture notes in mathematics **269**).

When pulling BibTeX references from [MathSciNet](https://mathscinet.ams.org) (or its freely accessible [lookup tool](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mrlookup)), I noticed that many (most?) books in series (Lecture notes in mathematics, Ergebnisse der Mathematik und ihrer Grenzgebiete, Mathematical Surveys and Monographs, ...) use the `VOLUME` field instead of `NUMBER`.

Especially with BibLaTeX this can lead to things like

> Author, A., *Book title*, volume 269. Lecture notes in mathematics.

This is clearly not the desired outcome, and the reason is that the wrong field was used.

(It seems that BibTeX does not have problems with this, and I get the impression that `VOLUME` and `NUMBER` are used interchangeably for `@book` and `@inbook` entries, at leat when a `SERIES` is present.)