# Workaround for missing archivePrefix in bib entry

Tags: biblatex

Using `bib` entries exported from http://adsabs.harvard.edu sometimes the field `archivePrefix` is missing. One example is this paper: http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2003A%26A...410..389R

As a result of the missing prefix, the hyperlink to the preprint is build incorrectly and does not work.

Of course I could add it manually each time, but as this effects roughly 20% of the ADS preprints (based on the limited and maybe biased survey of papers I cite in my work) I'd like to have some workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following workaround makes `arxiv` the default value of `archivePrefix`

```
\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map{
      \step[fieldset=archivePrefix,fieldvalue=arxiv]
    }
  }
}
```

In case you specify some value in your `.bib` file your value will be used, `arxiv` is only used if nothing is specified.

For me this workaround works flawlessly, but depending on the style you use, this might have undesired effects, so when applying this fix, please check carefully if you still get your desired output.

Comment: With `biblatex` `archivePrefix` is an alias for `eprinttype`, so you could also set `eprinttype` to `arxiv` if you wanted.

Comment: @moewe Thanks for the hint. Do you see any advantages/disadvantages for one or the other? I briefly considered using `eprinttype`, as this field is ultimately called when glueing together the link, but as I could not find any different behaviour I thought `archivePrefix` to be more intuitive as this is what ADS normally exports - but if there is a real difference I would gladly change this.

Comment: No, there is a source-mapping that maps `archivePrefix` to `eprinttype` so they are equivalent. I prefer `eprinttype` because `archivePrefix` is the alias, and `eprinttype` is what the bibmacros actually use. But it makes sense to use `archivePrefix` if that is what ADS normally uses and is missing here.