# Is this website building .bib correctly?

Tags: bibtex

I am wondering if this website is building `.bib` files correctly. 
Could someone verify, by exporting `.bib` and taking a look?

To export `.bib` you can go to this link

http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S2214109X16302091

[image: exporting .bib]

Comment: (1) welcome, (2) depends on your expectations and what you are going to use it for. In this case the `author` part might be problematic with standard `bibtex` as it contains non-ascii letters. On the other hand `biblatex` would like the `author` field just fine. Then getting bibtex data from online resources, always go through the data and adjust to your specific needs. No-one is perfect, at least not computers.

Comment: Have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/386053/software-generated-bibliographic-entries-common-errors-and-other-mistakes-to-ch to check for some common problems

Comment: Please add the resulting bib entry you got to your question. I think it is not neccessary to force other people to visit that page ... (btw: do one have to login?)

Comment: Apart from the points raised in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/386053/ (not all apply, of course) the only problem I see is that the `doi` field should ideally only contain the DOI and not `http://dx.doi.org/`