# google scholar bibtex and apa format

Tags: bibliographies, apa-style

I've writen my Ph.D. thesis and have imported all the references from google scholar. Now, at the end of the day(!), I have noticed that they are not compatible with each other. Here are some examples of what I have got from google and my problems:

```
@inproceedings{finin2010annotating,
      title={Annotating named entities in Twitter data with crowdsourcing},
      author={Finin, Tim and Murnane, Will and Karandikar, Anand and Keller, Nicholas and Martineau, Justin and Dredze, Mark},
      booktitle={Proceedings of the NAACL HLT 2010 Workshop on Creating Speech and Language Data with Amazon's Mechanical Turk},
      pages={80--88},
      year={2010},
      organization={Association for Computational Linguistics}
    }

@inproceedings{leidner2003grounding,
  title={Grounding spatial named entities for information extraction and question answering},
  author={Leidner, Jochen L and Sinclair, Gail and Webber, Bonnie},
  booktitle={Proceedings of the HLT-NAACL 2003 workshop on Analysis of geographic references-Volume 1},
  pages={31--38},
  year={2003},
  organization={Association for Computational Linguistics}
}
```

1) As you can see, `HLT-NAACL` is written differently in the two references.

2) Some referencse have `organization` (like the above examples) and some don't.

3) There are some acrynoms (for instance, `ACL` in the above examples for `Association for Computational Linguistics`) which are used for some references, but for some not. That is, in some cases I have the full name and in some cases, I have just the short form.

4) The google scholar doesn't have all the information for all papers/books. For example, I have a reference like this:

```
@article{fillmore1967case,
  title={The case for case.},
  author={Fillmore, Charles J},
  year={1967},
  publisher={ERIC}
}
```

In my code, I am using `\bibliographystyle{apacite}` (see my code at the end) and in the text, it looks good and everything is fine, but in the reference list, there are the above shortcomings.

Now, I have the following questions:

Is there anyway to make all the references compatible?

Does `APA` need `Organization` for each reference? If it doesn't why does mym code show it at the end of the references which have it, and if it does, why don't I get any error or warning regarding that? Is there anyway to make the code do that?

Generally speaking, what can I do to make my references similar to each other?

My code (if helps):

```
\documentclass[11pt, oneside]{Thesis}
\begin{document}

\label{Bibliography}
\bibliographystyle{apacite}
%\bibliographystyle{apa} 

\bibliography{Bibliography} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: There is not much that can be done automatically. You will have to go through all your entries and check for errors and other problems and then adjust them.

Comment: You cannot save a lot of time using predefined bib entries. You have to fix the stuff that is wrong. Just as with the terrible template you are using.

Comment: The portion of your posting that's related to Google Scholar is clearly off-topic for this site. Google Scholar relies on a lot of volunteers to create the bibliographic entries. To expect such entries to adhere to consistent style guidelines-- let alone be factually correct and complete -- is not realistic. You must anticipate performing a lot of checking and hand-correcting of whatever you obtain from Google Scholar. Please edit your posting to focus it on what the `apacite` bibliography style can and/or should be expected to do, in terms of creating formatted bibliographic entries.

Comment: It might be worth a look at [Software-generated bibliographic entries: common errors and other mistakes to check before use](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/386053/105447).