# I found no \citation commands after latex-bibtex-latex-latex (TextMaker + JabRef)

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, texmaker, biber, jabref

This seems to be a common problem, I read all the post here but can't fix the error

```
This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (MiKTeX 2.9.6350 64-bit) The top-level auxiliary file: revision6.aux I found no \citation commands---while reading file revision6.aux I found no \bibdata command---while reading file revision6.aux I found no \bibstyle command---while reading file revision6.aux (There were 3 error messages)

Process exited with error(s)
```

My code is super simple, just usepackage with backend and style for biblatex. Then I cited with the key generated by JabRef

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage[letterpaper, margin=1in]{geometry} % page settings
\usepackage{floatrow}
\floatsetup[table]{capposition=top}

\usepackage{authblk}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[ruled]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\allsectionsfont{\normalsize}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {./figures/} }
\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption}

\setlength{\parindent}{7mm}

\usepackage[backend=biber,style=numeric]{biblatex} 
\addbibresource{ABCbib.bib}
\title{ABC}
\begin{document}
\maketitle

\section{Introduction}
    proteins \cite{Zhang2013}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

The bib file looks like

```
@Article{Zhang2013,
  author        = {Yaoyang Zhang and Bryan R. Fonslow and Bing Shan and Moon-Chang Baek and John R. Yates},
  title         = {Protein Analysis by Shotgun/Bottom-up Proteomics},
  journal       = {Chemical Reviews},
  year          = {2013},
  volume        = {113},
  number        = {4},
  pages         = {2343--2394},
  month         = {apr},
  doi           = {10.1021/cr3003533},
  publisher     = {American Chemical Society ({ACS})},
}
```

EDIT: Then I tried both `latex (or PdfLaTeX) -> Biber -> latex (or PdfLaTeX) -> latex (or PdfLaTeX)` and got the error with warning `Citation Zhang2013 on Page 1 undefined`. May someone please guide me here? The configure is already changed to `biber.exe` and I input `biber %` for using as user command. But the error remains and ask me to rerun biber.

Comment: As you are specifying in your biblatex options `backend=biber` you must run `(pdf)latex` -> `biber` -> `(pdf)latex`, and not `bibtex`.

Comment: @gusbrs The tool in TexMaker does not have `biber` in the list. What to do to command `biber`?

Comment: Take a look at this answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/154788/105447, which gives details on how to configure TeXmaker to run biber and then tell us if it worked.

Comment: @gusbrs When I run `biber`, I got `Process exited with error(s)`

Comment: I compiled your example without any problems. Try to delete all auxiliary files before compiling.

Comment: If you are getting errors, we need to know which. Check the `.blg` file. Please not that if you only just installed `biblatex` or made an update in the last two days you might have run into the problem that `biblatex` 3.8 is already released, but Biber 2.8 had some build problems and could not be released yet. You'll have to wait until these issues are resolved.

Comment: Same result after delete `.aux` files. I think I installed it today. Anything I can do here? @gusbrs @moewe

Comment: By the way, `.blg` does not have anything inside. Can I manually add bib file I already made into LaTeX file?

Comment: If you did install it today, there might indeed be a problem. I suggest that, in the meantime, you use bibtex. That means changing your biblatex option to `backend=bibtex` and reverting changes in your texmaker so that it runs bibtex. I'm not sure how long it's gonna take to fix things, but I can presume that in some days time, you can try again biber (and I do recommend you do so, bibtex is currently a legacy option for biblatex.)

Comment: Sorry, I don't. I'm a linux user myself, and thus not into the installation paths of MikTeX. But someonelse here certainly does. Still, I'd guess the same way you found the path to biber should work for bibtex too. @moewe, do you know it?

Comment: @gusbrs I found it, so sorry. It works but just get the warning `Package biblatex Warning: Biber reported the following issues
(biblatex) with 'Nesvi2005':
(biblatex) - Invalid format of field 'month`. Why does `biber` still have problem here?

Comment: Clear all temporary files and try again. If you use BibTeX it should be BibTeX that complains.

Comment: So biber is working, then! Well, I can't reproduce your warning, but you could try to substitute both your `year` and `month` fields by `date = {2013-04},`.

Comment: @gusbrs thank you so much. Let me try this later. The manuscript is due in 3 hours. So sorry. I will fix and comment again. @ moewe

Comment: `month = {apr},` is wrong, `month = {4},` would be acceptable, but `date = {2013-04}` is generally better. See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/386058/35864

Comment: I tried `biber` again and got `Package biblatex Warning: Please (re)run Biber on the file:`. But while I rerun Biber from user command,  I got `Process exited with error(s)`. Here is Biber 2.7 @gusbrs

Comment: I delete the month here and also clear all temp file before run. It doesn't work. In user command, at command (% without extension), I type the word `biber %` in. Is this correct? @moewe

Comment: If you are running MikTeX and updated `biblatex` to version 3.9 in the last days you can't use Biber since that is still at the incompatible version 2.7. The problem is being worked on at the moment, currently the only solution is to go back to `biblatex` 3.7 (not that easy) or switch to BibTeX. Please show us the error messages you get, 'Process exited with error(s)' is not enough.

Comment: When I tried to use `biber`, the error was shown only that sentence. So I switch to `BibTeX` now. Although `BibTeX` creates PdfLaTeX ok, `biber` warning (about the month) appears. Why I got `Biber` warning after switching? My biblatex is v.3.8 @moewe

Comment: That is probably your editor hiding the rest of the error message from you. Normally you would find something in the `.blg` file, if not you can compile from the command line to see the error.

Comment: Indeed the warning says "Biber" even if you run BibTeX, this is just a problem with the warning and nothing you have to worry about.

Comment: You'll be happy to know that Biber 2.8 has been released. So you can use `biblatex` 3.8(a) with Biber again.