# Making a consistent bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, bibdesk

Using several books and papers, I've gotten a reasonably sized list of references in my BibDesk .bib file. Some of them came from Google Scholar, others from websites such as Springer. I've noticed that the resulting bibliography file is inconsistent, that is some entries mess up the capitalization, and also the convention for displaying the Authors' names is not uniform (full name vs. shortened).

Is there a way of having all references use the same style (except for manually modifying the differences)?

Thank you!

Comment: vaguely related question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/386053/software-generated-bibliographic-entries-common-errors-and-other-mistakes-to-ch

Comment: I recommend using a ref manager. Probably, you can even just import your inconsistent bib file, look through the titles in the bib manager, then export as bibtex and you will have a clean file. As for ref managers, I think there's a list on wikipedia. I personally like citavi, but the big one's like Mendeley, JabRef and Zotero all have great export functions to TeX, I hear, to varying degrees of greatness, depending on your preferences.

Comment: No, you are in charge of making the database entries consistent. Such generators don't provide good (or even true) results.