# ! Paragraph ended before \name was complete

Tags: biblatex, biber, accents, braces

I recently upgraded my texlive packages at home and I cannot compile my document anymore due to the references. I googled for it for several days already and I cannot find anything recent about this issue (it does pop up from time to time apparently). Most of my entries are extracted from ADS (particularly the ones that give me troubles).

Here is a minimal entry with one of such troublesome entries.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@ARTICLE{2013APh....50...26A,
  author = {{Abeysekara}, A.~U. and {Alfaro}, R. and {Alvarez}, C. and {{\'A}lvarez}, J.~D. and
    {Tollefson}, K. and {Torres}, I. and {Ukwatta}, T.~N. and {Villase{\~n}or}, L. and
    {Weisgarber}, T. and {Westerhoff}, S. and {Wisher}, I.~G. and
    {Wood}, J. and {Yodh}, G.~B. and {Younk}, P.~W. and {Zaborov}, D. and
    {Zepeda}, A. and {Zhou}, H.},
  title = "{Sensitivity of the high altitude water Cherenkov detector to sources of multi-TeV gamma rays}",
  journal = {Astroparticle Physics},
  archivePrefix = "arXiv",
  eprint = {1306.5800},
  primaryClass = "astro-ph.HE",
  keywords = {TeV gamma-ray astronomy, Water cherenkov, Cosmic ray},
    year = 2013,
  month = dec,
  volume = 50,
  pages = {26-32},
  doi = {10.1016/j.astropartphys.2013.08.002},
  adsurl = {http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2013APh....50...26A},
  adsnote = {Provided by the SAO/NASA Astrophysics Data System}
}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[language=english, style=numeric-comp, sorting=none, backend=biber, natbib=true, doi=false, bibencoding=utf8, isbn=false]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname}

\begin{document}
This is a simple document\cite{2013APh....50...26A}
\end{document}
```

The error I get is

```
Runaway argument?
{{{hash=8b556f9238232cff536971111edddb4b}{family={{Abeysekara}}, fami\ETC.
! Paragraph ended before \name was complete.
<to be read again> 
               \par 
l.140   
?
```

I guess the issue comes from the combination of curly braces + accents and other 'weird characters'.

I am using biber 2.10 and texlive 2017.45XXX (current archlinux's version).

At work, where it works fine, I'm using texlive 2017.44XXX and biber 2.7

Anything I can do about it apart from trying to downgrade my texlive (which is an ugly solution)?

Comment: What does it do, if you try to clean up your bib file to have a consistent format?

Comment: If I remove the braces around the family names it does compile. But I have hundreds (if not thousands) of these multiple author entries extracted from ADS. If I have to manually correct them I rather I will become a bit crazy. Any way of dealing with it without doing the manual edits?

Comment: @Mireia Unfortunately, those braces are the cause for the error; they are *wrong* for multiple reasons.

Comment: And why are they working with previous biblatex/biber versions?

Comment: Hmm... I see the problem. You could try feeding them to a ref manager and check the entries therein. Then export to a bib file. This way, at least, you're sure to have all braces and commas around fields, where they need to be. Other problems might arise, but my guess is there will be a lot less than doing the whole work by hand. Cf. egreg's answer, where he manually cleaned up the entries. There might be some other crazy wizard way, but I can't imagine there is.

Answer (score 6):

had the same problem, figured out now: you shall **not nest braces 3+ levels deep**.

as @gusbrs notices it has to do with the names--but only because noting accented letters in braces needs another level of nesting.

so, 
  `author = {{ÖKO} Friendly Company},`
would work, but
  `author = {{{\"O}KO} Friendly Company},` would not anymore.

even if the braces are balanced, there's an error.
so `author = {{{a}}},` will work, but `author = {{{a} {b}}},` will not.

The last notation will throw an `! Paragraph ended before \name was complete.` error.

Try to remove as much braces as possible, use utf8 encoding as already mentioned, should be enough for your entries.

N.B.: `biber --tool -V *.bib` will *not* warn you about that.

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)!

Answer (score 5):

Egreg's recommendations are very good, but it is easy to understand your situation. I tried to narrow down what was causing the problem and, as it turns out, it is one of the names `{{\'A}lvarez}`. Somehow, that is resulting in a .bbl file with unbalanced braces, which gives you problems in your compilation. Once you are using `bibencoding=utf8` you can change it to `{Álvarez}` and get rid of the error. I don't have your other problematic cases at hand, but my guess is the doble braces at the start cause the problem (even though I don't understand why they should cause a problem at all). If this is the case, the number of instances for you to fix would be already much, much smaller.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@ARTICLE{2013APh....50...26A,
  author = {{Abeysekara}, A.~U. and {Alfaro}, R. and {Alvarez}, C. and {Álvarez}, J.~D. and {Tollefson}, K. and {Torres}, I. and {Ukwatta}, T.~N. and {Villase{\~n}or}, L. and {Weisgarber}, T. and {Westerhoff}, S. and {Wisher}, I.~G. and {Wood}, J. and {Yodh}, G.~B. and {Younk}, P.~W. and {Zaborov}, D. and {Zepeda}, A. and {Zhou}, H.},
  title = "{Sensitivity of the high altitude water Cherenkov detector to sources of multi-TeV gamma rays}",
  journal = {Astroparticle Physics},
  archivePrefix = "arXiv",
  eprint = {1306.5800},
  primaryClass = "astro-ph.HE",
  keywords = {TeV gamma-ray astronomy, Water cherenkov, Cosmic ray},
    year = 2013,
  month = dec,
  volume = 50,
  pages = {26-32},
  doi = {10.1016/j.astropartphys.2013.08.002},
  adsurl = {http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2013APh....50...26A},
  adsnote = {Provided by the SAO/NASA Astrophysics Data System}
}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[language=english, style=numeric-comp, sorting=none, backend=biber, natbib=true, bibencoding=utf8, doi=false, isbn=false]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
This is a simple document\cite{2013APh....50...26A}
\end{document}
```

Comment: There are lots of them more, like {\'a}, {\'{\i}} and lots of other combinations. I know they are not correctly formatted, but trust me ADS is a huge source of bib files for the astronomical community.

Comment: If my guess is correct, only those in the first letter of the names will cause you problem (I don't think they should!). You see in my example `{Villase{\~n}or}` is there working fine.

Comment: Still, egreg is right in pointing that the braces are conceptually wrong. Supplied by the ADS or not. By the way, the problems with software generated entries are many and common. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/386053/105447.

Comment: If you think that it is the case, you might want to report the issue at `biber`'s github: https://github.com/plk/biber/issues

Comment: I had the same problem with several entries with the name {\"O}berg in the ADS bibtex exports. This should definitely be reported to the ADS developers https://github.com/adsabs/export_service/issues

Comment: @MigueldeVal-Borro, the issue has been reported to the biber developers and fixed in the current development version (3.11), which is promised to reach distribution sometime soon. I'm not an user of the ADS bibtex exporting myself, but if you think reporting it to the ADS developers is also a good idea, of course you might as well do that.

Answer (score 3):

If I remove all the (wrong) braces around family names, there is no issue.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@ARTICLE{2013APh....50...26A,
  author = {Abeysekara, A. U. and Alfaro, R. and Alvarez, C. and 
            {\'A}lvarez, J. D. and Tollefson, K. and Torres, I. and
            Ukwatta, T. N. and Villase{\ n}or, L. and Weisgarber, T. and
            Westerhoff, S. and Wisher, I. G. and
            Wood, J. and Yodh, G. B. and Younk, P. W. and Zaborov, D. and
            Zepeda, A. and Zhou, H.},
  title = {Sensitivity of the high altitude water {Cherenkov} detector to 
           sources of multi-{TeV} gamma rays},
  journal = {Astroparticle Physics},
  archivePrefix = {arXiv},
  eprint = {1306.5800},
  primaryClass = {astro-ph.HE},
  keywords = {TeV gamma-ray astronomy, Water cherenkov, Cosmic ray},
    year = 2013,
  month = dec,
  volume = 50,
  pages = {26-32},
  doi = {10.1016/j.astropartphys.2013.08.002},
  adsurl = {http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2013APh....50...26A},
  adsnote = {Provided by the SAO/NASA Astrophysics Data System}
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[
  language=english,
  style=numeric-comp,
  sorting=none,
%  backend=biber,
  natbib=true,
  doi=false,
%  bibencoding=utf8,
  isbn=false
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
This is a simple document~\cite{2013APh....50...26A}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Also wrong are the `~` between initials. The argument to `\addbibresource` should contain the `.bib` extension.

Comment: As mentioned in the previous comment, ADS generated the entries (it's my PhD thesis) and there are too many of them to manually edit them. Any way of dealing with it without editing by hand?

Comment: @Mireia I'm afraid the answer is no. What is ADS?

Comment: egreg, those are good recommendations, of course, but should this bring compilation to a halt? Braces are balanced in his entry, and this results in a .bbl file with unbalanced braces.

Comment: @gusbrs I think that Biber gets confused with accents. Maybe the issue can be fixed, but the braces around the names are wrong nonetheless.

Comment: ADS = SAO/NASA's Astrophysics Data System http://adsabs.harvard.edu/

Comment: Can't it be solved with some sort of \DeclareSourcemap code inside the .tex ?

Comment: By the way, if I ask Google Scholar, the data format is good: https://scholar.googleusercontent.com/scholar.bib?q=info:auZXsMmf52kJ:scholar.google.com/&output=citation&scisig=AAGBfm0AAAAAWn871Tw_ta92Psfkb9lkhoDBG3xxrcw_&scisf=4&ct=citation&cd=-1&hl=it&scfhb=1

Comment: @Mireia I don't really know why ADS adds those braces: they are conceptually wrong, because they break sorting or, at the least, make it difficult.

Comment: egreg, suppose I have a corporate author which starts with `{\'A}`.

Comment: gusbrs ... {\'Alvarez} just like {\v Cerenkov} works fine.

Comment: I have reported the issue in biber's github

Answer (score 0):

Just for people with the same problem: Download the newest biber version from 
[sourceforge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/biblatex-biber/files/biblatex-biber/current/binaries/) (2.11 did the trick for me) and install it.

On linux, you just have to unpack the zip-file and move the biber executable to the appropriate place:

```
which biber
  /usr/bin/biber

sudo mv /usr/bin/biber /usr/bin/biber.old

sudo mv ./biber /usr/bin/biber
```

That fixed the problem for me. If I find some problems associated to this partial update down the line, I will report them here.

Comment: Note that in general manual updates of Biber (or `biblatex`) are *strongly* discouraged. In particular just updating to Biber 2.11 without also having a Biber version that is compatible with it can seriously brake things. If you want to update `biblatex` or Biber always use the update facilities (`tlmgr` or MikTeX console) of your TeX distribution.

Answer (score 0):

Just an update for what helped me (because none of the previous answers didn't):
there are **required** fields, when you define your `bibliography.bib` file (or another file), in particular I was missing `volume=` in one of the `@article`'s, which caused biber to generate some inappropriate structures.

TLDR: keep an eye on defining all required fields in bibliography, even if You don't need them (You can always write `volume=""`).

Comment: Missing `volume` fields like should not result in errors like this. If you can reproduce the error in a small example document, please report this at https://github.com/plk/biber/issues. That would be a bug.