# biblatex-chicago does not print origyear with cmsdate=both

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, biblatex-chicago

In the MWE below, biblatex-chicago with option `cmsdate=both`, instead of printing the origyear and year like this **([1956] 1980)**  it prints the year twice **([1980] 1980)**, both in the intext citations as well as in the bibliography entry.

```
\documentclass{article}   %
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\usepackage[authordate, backend=biber,%
    bookpages=false, isbn=false, doi=false, numbermonth=false,% don't print doi, isbn, (total) pages for books, and month in articles
    mincrossrefs=10,% only include the @collection when more than 10 @incollections unless explicitly cited
    longcrossref=true,% no abbreviated citations of @incollection, @inbook, etc. 
    cmsdate=both]% print both, origdate and date >> change to =off to only print date
    {biblatex-chicago}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{cms-american}
\addbibresource{Bibliography.bib}

\begin{document}
\autocite{Jakobson:1980} 
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Relevant bibfile entry:

```
@inbook{Jakobson:1980,
    Author = {Jakobson, Roman},
    Booktitle = {The Framework of Language},
    Location = {Ann Arbor},
    Origyear = {1956},
    Pages = {81--92},
    Publisher = {University of Michigan Press},
    Shorttitle = {Metalanguage as a Linguistic Problem},
    Title = {Metalanguage as a Linguistic Problem},
    Year = {1980}}
```

Has been working fine before. Unsure where to look for the error.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Why does this happen?

**`origyear` is not** a **supported** input field, the correct field to use would be **`origdate`**.

As a rule of thumb the correct field is always `...date`, you should never use the separate fields `...year`, `...month` or `...day`. The only exception is `year` which is accepted for compatibility reasons, but even there `date` is strongly preferred over `year`.

You will find that while `origdate` is listed in the list of known fields in §2.2.2 *Data Fields*, `origyear` is not. `origyear` is only mentioned in §4.2.4.3 *Date Component Fields*, but that is a subsection of §4.2.4 *Special Fields* which begins with (emphasis mine)

> The following lists and fields are used by `biblatex` to pass data to bibliography drivers and citation commands. **They are not used in `bib` files but defined automatically by the package.** From the perspective of a bibliography or citation style, they are not different from the fields in a `bib` file.

So the documentation is pretty clear that `origyear` should not be used in the `.bib` file. The fact that it almost works is an artefact of how Biber parses `...date` fields.

### What is the specific problem here?

If you give
`year = {1980}, origyear = {1956}` you will end up with

```
\field{labeldatesource}{year}
\field{origyear}{1956}
\field{year}{1980}
```

in the `.bbl` file. But with the correct `date = {1980}, origdate = {1956},` you get

```
\field{labeldatesource}{orig}
\field{origyear}{1956}
\field{year}{1980}
\field{dateera}{ce}
\field{origdateera}{ce}
```

The entries for `...dateera` are not that relevant here, but what is important for us is the `\field{labeldatesource}` line. The line shows us that in the first case `year` is taken to be the primary labeldate, while in the second case `origdate` is responsible for the labeldate.

Now `biblatex-chicago` has some *really* complicated code for the date handling, but in essence the code always assumes that the `labeldate`  follows

```
\DeclareLabeldate{
  \field{origdate}
  \field{date}
  \field{year}
  \field{eventdate}
  \field{urldate}}
```

and thus gives `origdate` preference over `date`, i.e. if both `origdate` and `date`/`year` are present `origdate` makes it to `labeldate`. If `origyear` is used that does not happen.

That is where `biblatex-chicago` gets confused: It assumes that since both `origyear` and `year` are present, the first must also be equal to `labelyear`. So it prints `labelyear` and `year`. But as it turns out `labelyear` is `year`, so it just prints the same year twice.

### How can this be fixed?

Definitely by using the correct input

```
@inbook{Jakobson:1980,
  author    = {Jakobson, Roman},
  title     = {Metalanguage as a Linguistic Problem},
  date      = {1980},
  booktitle = {The Framework of Language},
  publisher = {University of Michigan Press},
  location  = {Ann Arbor},
  origdate  = {1956},
  pages     = {81--92},
}
```

If you are using a reference manager to write your `.bib` file there should be a way to use `origdate` instead of `origyear`. Even if you are not, it is fairly simple to do a search and replace of `origyear` to `origdate` in your `.bib` file (that is all that is required if you never have an `origmonth`).

If you must have a solution with the broken `.bib` file you can try

```
\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map{
      \step[fieldsource=origyear, fieldtarget=origdate, final]
      \step[fieldset=origyear, null]
      \step[fieldsource=origmonth, final]
      \step[fieldset=origdate, fieldvalue=-, append]
      \step[fieldset=origdate,  origfieldval, append]
      \step[fieldsource=origmonth, null]
      \step[fieldsource=origday, final]
      \step[fieldset=origdate, fieldvalue=-, append]
      \step[fieldset=origdate,  origfieldval, append]
      \step[fieldsource=origday, null]
    }
  }
}
```

or for `origyear` only

```
\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map{
      \step[fieldsource=origyear, fieldtarget=origdate, final]
      \step[fieldset=origyear, null]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks much, that's a thorough explanation!  I'm certainly going to update the bibfile, with `origyear` > `origdate` but also `year` > `date`.  I've been holding off of that mainly because most sources from the internet use `year` but I'll try to come up with a way that automatically changes that upon import.

Comment: @jan, internet sources will usually use `year` so as to be compatible with bot BibTeX and biblatex, even though `date` is preferred for latter (unfortunately, the same doesn't work with `origyear` in your case). But some care is due with entries we get from software generated entries (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/386053/105447).

Comment: Ah, the Source map does handle this. I was afraid the "parsed level" and the "input level" might interfere with each other there. Also, hadn't figured what `biblatex-chicago` was doing there. (+1!)

Comment: @gusbrs Sourcemaps are applied before most of the processing happens (the docs say  "Source mapping happens during data parsing and therefore before any other operation such as inheritance and sorting.") They mostly operate on the raw input. I say 'mostly' because the conversion of macros into UTF-8 happens before the sourcemapping (if I understand correctly).

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what changed recently in `biblatex-chicago` in this respect. But the manual refers to `origdate` and `date`, which is in line with `biblatex`'s terminology. Indeed, with these fields, it works as expected.

```
@inbook{Jakobson:1980,
    Author = {Jakobson, Roman},
    Booktitle = {The Framework of Language},
    Location = {Ann Arbor},
    Origdate = {1956},
    Pages = {81--92},
    Publisher = {University of Michigan Press},
    Shorttitle = {Metalanguage as a Linguistic Problem},
    Title = {Metalanguage as a Linguistic Problem},
    Date = {1980}}
```

Results in:

[image]

Comment: Ah, cool, hmm ... I guess I have to update my database  :(  Unless, do you know of an easy way to automatically convert year fields to date fields on the go?

Comment: Mmh, dates are tricky... I think a sourcemap might not get the job done in this case. But I don't know what may have changed in `biblatex-chicago`, if anything. Perhaps someone more informed about it may be able to provide better advice.

Comment: Also, as far as I understand how this works, I'd expect `year` and `origyear` to work. In other words, I cannot really tell you what is going wrong. This answer may help you, but let's see what others have to say.

Comment: Yeah, sounds good.  It certainly has been working before (although I can't tell when exactly it stopped, just noticed today).  And I just checked the documentation, it nowhere states that `year` would be deprecated (although `date` is, of course, preferred).