# Changing comma to semicolon before citation with the acro package

Tags: citing, acronyms, acro

I am using the `acro` package to introduce acronyms with appropriate citations. I am *almost* able to get what I need, but with one small issue.

I would like to introduce acronyms in the form "Helioseismic and Magnetic Imager (HMI; Scherrer et al., 2012)", but so far with the `acro` package, I have only been able to get "Helioseismic and Magnetic Imager (HMI, Scherrer et al., 2012)" -- *i.e.*, with a comma separating the acronym and the citation instead of a semicolon.

Here is my working example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{bibliography.bib}
@article{scherrer2012helioseismic,
author = {{Scherrer}, P.~H. and {Schou}, J. and {Bush}, R.~I. and {Kosovichev}, A.~G. and {Bogart}, R.~S. and {Hoeksema}, J.~T. and {Liu}, Y. and {Duvall}, T.~L. and {Zhao}, J. and {Title}, A.~M. and {Schrijver}, C.~J. and {Tarbell}, T.~D. and {Tomczyk}, S.},
title = "{The Helioseismic and Magnetic Imager (HMI) Investigation for the Solar Dynamics Observatory (SDO)}",
year = 2012}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage[natbib,citestyle=authoryear,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}

\usepackage{acro}
\acsetup{
  single         = false,
  sort           = true,
  group-citation = true,
  group-cite-cmd = \citealp
}

\DeclareAcronym{HMI}{
  short = HMI,
  long = Helioseismic and Magnetic Imager,
  cite = {scherrer2012helioseismic}
}

\begin{document}

I need this to say ``Helioseismic and Magnetic Imager (HMI; Scherrer et al., 2012)''.

But right now, I get ``\ac{HMI}''.

\end{document}
```

Is it possible to change the separator between the acronym and citation from a comma to a semicolon?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Analogous to `cite`'s `cite-connect` `group-citation` has `group-cite-connect`, which for some reason is not documented in v2.8 of the `acro` manual (I complained about that https://bitbucket.org/cgnieder/acro/issues/110/group-cite-connect-not-documented).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{bibliography.bib}
@article{scherrer2012helioseismic,
author = {{Scherrer}, P.~H. and {Schou}, J. and {Bush}, R.~I. and {Kosovichev}, A.~G. and {Bogart}, R.~S. and {Hoeksema}, J.~T. and {Liu}, Y. and {Duvall}, T.~L. and {Zhao}, J. and {Title}, A.~M. and {Schrijver}, C.~J. and {Tarbell}, T.~D. and {Tomczyk}, S.},
title = "{The Helioseismic and Magnetic Imager (HMI) Investigation for the Solar Dynamics Observatory (SDO)}",
year = 2012}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage[natbib,citestyle=authoryear,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}

\usepackage{acro}
\acsetup{
  single         = false,
  sort           = true,
  group-citation = true,
  group-cite-cmd = \citealp,
  group-cite-connect = {; },
}

\DeclareAcronym{HMI}{
  short = HMI,
  long = Helioseismic and Magnetic Imager,
  cite = {scherrer2012helioseismic}
}

\begin{document}
I need this to say ``Helioseismic and Magnetic Imager (HMI; Scherrer et al., 2012)''.

But right now, I get ``\ac{HMI}''.
\end{document}
```

[image: "Helioseismic and Magnetic Imager (HMI; Scherrer et al., 2012)"]

You may want to have a look at [Software-generated bibliographic entries: common errors and other mistakes to check before use](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/386053/35864) for your `.bib` entry: The braces around author family names are wrong and could lead to errors. The `~` ties are not needed in the initials with `biblatex`. The `title` field should not be wrapped in additional curly braces. Lastly you probably want a `journal` and `volume` as well as a `pages` field if this is indeed an `@article`.

Comment: Thank you! Adding ``group-cite-connect = {; }`` to the \acsetup was exactly what I needed!

Comment: Fabulous! I can use this for my own thesis.