# Acronym package - merge first occurence of acronym with following citation/parentheses

Tags: citing, acronyms

I am using the `acronym` package. It happens often in my texts that I have something like:

```
1. We first use a \ac{NA} \citep{exocom2019} and then the text continues.

2. We learn a \ac{VL} (i.e., something we did not know before).
```

What will look like the following in a text.

> 1. We first use a New Acronym (NA) (Exocom, 2019) and then the text continues.
> 2. We learn a Valuable Lesson (VL) (i.e., something we did not know before).

Is there a way in the `acronym` package to do this so that I can merge the parentheses? In a way the output becomes something like:

> 1. We first use a New Acronym (NA; Exocom, 2019) and then the text continues.
> 2. We learn a Valuable Lesson (VL; i.e., something we did not know before).

In case somebody has another good solution or workaround to the problem, please let me know.

PS: I tried to update the examples and add code as asked. I hope that helps.

PPS: An MWE

--- mwe.tex ---

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}

\usepackage[printonlyused]{acronym} % used for the nice acronyms
\usepackage[style=authoryear-comp,citestyle=authoryear,natbib=true,backend=bibtex,maxbibnames=99,maxcitenames=1]{biblatex} %NEW BIB: needed so that bibentry works

\bibliography{mweBib}

\begin{document}

\begin{acronym}
    \acro{NA}{New Acronym} 
    \acro{VL}{Valuable Lesson} 
\end{acronym}

1. We first use a \ac{NA} \citep{exocom2019} and then the text continues.

2. We learn a \ac{VL} (i.e., something we did not know before).
\end{document}
```

--- mweBib.bib ---

```
@inproceedings{exocom2019,
  title={My title},
  author={Exocom},
  year={2019},
  booktitle = {Proc. Stackexchange}
}
```

--- command ---

```
latexmk -pvc mwe.tex
```

Comment: It is quite hard to follow what you are asking. To be able to reproduce the issue, please post a compilable code sample.

Comment: I don't know how to do it with citations, but with `normal` parenthesis you could solve the problem by hand with explicit commands: `\acl{NA} (\acs{NA}; ....)`

Comment: I can imho not use the \acl{} and \acs combination, as this leads to the acronym being written out fully twice. Once where I do it by hand and once by the package that thinks the next time it encounters an \ac{} it has not been introduced yet.

Comment: I believe this is something [`acro`](https://ctan.org/pkg/acro) supports with the `cite` key/`group-citation` package option, though I've never used it.  See [this question/answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/444290/106162) for an example.

Comment: @Exocom You could include an `\acused` command to prevent the acronym being fully printed twice.

Comment: @DaiBowen: Yes, thanks, that is true. For a few cases, this works.

Comment: @Ignasi: Thanks, this does work. Not a very elegant solution, but I did not ask for that ;-).

Answer (score 1):

This is doable with the `acro` package:

- The citation is already built in by setting the option `cite/group = true` and adding the citation to the definition of the acronym.
- A one-time addition is possible by redefining the default template…

  ```
    \RenewAcroTemplate{long-short}{%
      \acroiffirstTF{%
        \acrowrite{long}%
        \acspace(%
          \acroifT{foreign}{\acrowrite{foreign}, }%
          \acrowrite{short}%
          \acroifT{alt}{ \acrotranslate{or} \acrowrite{alt}}%
          \acaddition % <<< new
          \acrogroupcite
        )%
      }{%
        \acrowrite{short}%
        \acaddition % <<< new
      }%
    }
  ```

  …and the command `\ac`:

  ```
    \providecommand\acaddition{}
    \RenewAcroCommand\ac{mo}{%
      \IfNoValueF{#2}{\def\acaddition{, #2}}%
      \UseAcroTemplate{first}{#1}%
    }
  ```

  Commands defined by `\NewAcroCommand` and friends are local to a group so we don't need to worry about the definition of `\acaddition` afterwards.

A complete example:

[image]

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=authoryear-comp,citestyle=authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}


\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@inproceedings{exocom2019,
  title={My title},
  author={Exocom},
  year={2019},
  booktitle = {Proc. Stackexchange}
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage{acro}

\RenewAcroTemplate{long-short}{%
  \acroiffirstTF{%
    \acrowrite{long}%
    \acspace(%
      \acroifT{foreign}{\acrowrite{foreign}, }%
      \acrowrite{short}%
      \acroifT{alt}{ \acrotranslate{or} \acrowrite{alt}}%
      \acaddition % <<< new
      \acrogroupcite
    )%
  }{%
    \acrowrite{short}%
    \acaddition % <<< new
  }%
}

\providecommand\acaddition{}
\RenewAcroCommand\ac{mo}{%
  \IfNoValueF{#2}{\def\acaddition{, #2}}%
  \UseAcroTemplate{first}{#1}%
}

\acsetup{
  cite/group = true
}

\DeclareAcronym{NA}{
  short = NA ,
  long = New Acronym ,
  cite = exocom2019
}
\DeclareAcronym{VL}{
  short = VL ,
  long = Valuable Lesson
}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
  \item We first use a \ac{NA} and then the text continues.
  \item We learn a \ac{VL}[i.e., something we did not know before].
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```