# How to eliminate back-to-back parentheses caused by glossaries?

Tags: glossaries

I am using the `glossaries` package for acronyms. When first using an acronym using `\gls{}`, the entry is written as long form and the short form follows in parentheses. Sometimes, these are followed by parentheses already occuring in the sentence. Is there a way to merge the parentheses created by glossaries and the following one in the sentence? (For the `acro` package, this was apparently solved [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/504162/acronym-package-merge-first-occurence-of-acronym-with-following-citation-paren).)

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{glossaries}
\newacronym{SX}{SX}{Stack Exchange}
\makeglossaries
\begin{document}
Hello \gls{SX} (tex.stackexchange.com)!
\end{document}
```

Actual result: `Hello Stack Exchange (SX) (tex.stackexchange.com)!`
Desired result: `Hello Stack Exchange (SX, tex.stackexchange.com)!`

The goal is to eliminate back-to-back parentheses caused by glossaries.

Comment: I suggest rewriting the „Hello“ sentence, e.g. by putting the URL into a footnote, expanding its parentheses into a sentence or similar.

Comment: Thanks, but not appropriate in my use case. I have edited to include the desired result.

Comment: Thanks, that edit helps. However, it's still not clear enough: 1) what shall happen at the 2nd and more calls to `\gls{SX}`? 2) You wrote "sometimes" ... So what are the use cases all together? Can you please expand your desired result(s) with all variations in mind? Thank you

Comment: There are no more variations. The goal is to eliminate back-to-back parentheses caused by glossaries.