# Identify which ??? key is missing in bibtex

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex

I am struggling identifying which elements of a bibtex entry are missing, since when I compile the pdf output shows some entries with ???, for example:

[image]

This is the output for

```
@book{friedman2016introduction,
  title={Introduction to Apache Flink: Stream Processing for Real Time and Beyond},
  author={Friedman, E. and Ellen Friedman, M.D. and Tzoumas, K.},
  isbn={9781491977163},
  lccn={2017385514},
  year={2016},
  publisher={O'Reilly Media}
}
```

When facing this kind of problems, how could I identify which entry is missing?

Here is what I see on the .bbl file:

```
metafiles/bmc_article.bbl:\bpublisher{O'Reilly Media}, \blocation{???}
```

Comment: From `blocation` I'm guessing you are missing the `address` field. Your BibTeX log (`.blg`) should contain more warnings or error messages.

Comment: Odd-topic: you should check the author list - this book seems to have 2 authors only

Comment: The ISBN number is `978-1491976586` (checked to correspond to the book). The book has only two authors. The ISBN `9781491977163` is syntactically correct, but corresponds to nothing.

Comment: I found a few `.bst` files with `\blocation` on the web and it seems that they don't actually warn you with a message in the log (`.blg`) when they output `\blocation`. So this is probably something that should be mentioned in the documentation.  Otherwise it is pretty hard to know what is going wrong without looking at the `.bbl` and the source of the `.bst`. Can you show us a link to the `.bst` file you use?

Comment: @egreg JabRef produce a similar reference introducing just 9781491977163 as ISBN. Maybe is the code of the ebook version (the url is https://www.ebook.de/de/product/27779735/ellen_friedman_kostas_tzoumas_introduction_to_apache_flink.html)

Comment: @Fran Yeah, seems so.

Comment: Hello all, thanks for your comments, it seems that the only entry missing is indeed `\blocation`, but is not present in most of the .bib files I download when citing. As for the book I downloaded the reference from https://books.google.es/books/about/Introduction_to_Apache_Flink.html?id=g0RMDQAAQBAJ&source=kp_book_description&redir_esc=y, here it seems there are three authors.

Comment: If the style outputs `\blocation` when there is no `address` field, the obvious way to resolve that issue is by providing the `address` data. Published books should have that information on the cover page, you usually take the location of the publisher. The book behind the link definitely has only two authors as can be seen on the cover, the data exported to the `.bib` file is incorrect. Unfortunately that happens quite often, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/386053/35864

Comment: Add the field: `address={Sebastopol, CA, USA}`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

An internet search suggests that `\blocation` is used by several `.bst` files written by VTeX for various customers (see https://github.com/search?p=1&q=blocation+extension%3Abst+user%3Avtex-soft&type=Code). Going by the file name of your `.bbl` I guess you might be using `bmc-mathphys.bst` from https://www.biomedcentral.com/getpublished/writing-resources/additional-files which was also written by VTeX. The file contains

```
  address empty$
    { publisher empty$
        {howpublished} 
        {springer.publisher} 
      if$ 
       "publisher" make.tag
      #1 bother =
        {", \blocation{???}" *  }
        'skip$
       if$
       output   
    }
    {
      publisher empty$
        {howpublished } 
        {springer.publisher } 
       if$ 
      "publisher" make.tag output
      insert.comma
      address "location" make.tag output
    }
  if$
```

which shows that the file will output `\blocation{???}` to the `.bbl` if no `address` field is provided and the `bother` flag is set to one.

Note that the file does not issue a regular BibTeX warning as is customarily done by the standard styles in such cases. For example `plain.bst` has

```
number empty$
  'skip$
  { "(" number * ")" * *
    volume empty$
      { "there's a number but no volume in " cite$ * warning$ }
      'skip$
    if$
  }
if$
```

All that means that there is no real way of telling why you get question marks in your output other than going back to the `.bbl` and finding that they are produced by `\blocation{???}` and then going to the `.bst` and finding out that `\blocation{???}` is written to the `.bbl` if the `address` field is missing. Of course you might have guessed that already by the name of the command (incidentally `location` is the `biblatex` name of the `address` field).

So to solve the issue you should provide an `address` for the publisher, probably something like

```
address={Sebastopol, Calif.}
```

As discussed in the comments you will also want to check the `author` field of that work. The full entry should probably read

```
@book{friedman2016introduction,
  title     = {Introduction to Apache Flink: Stream Processing for Real Time and Beyond},
  author    = {Friedman, Ellen and Tzoumas, Kostas},
  isbn      = {9781491977163},
  year      = {2016},
  publisher = {O'Reilly Media}
  address   = {Sebastopol, Calif.}
}
```

Comment: +1 for all the detective work :)