# Modify Beamer Bibliography Style

Tags: beamer, bibliographies, bibtex

I am pretty newbie to LaTeX and Beamer theme customization.

I am using the Metropolis template (https://github.com/matze/mtheme).

Everything goes fine, but for the Bibliography: my code (identical to the template code) is:

```
\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]{References}

   \bibliography{demo}
   \bibliographystyle{abbrv}

\end{frame}
```

Now, Bibliography looks like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/wQRk2.jpg

As you can see, names are all abbreviated, even for "Influx Development Team",
and all uppercase letters are lowercased.

How can I fix this?

Changing `\bibliographystyle{x}` did not work, always same result.

**EDIT**

As samcarted suggested (ty btw), here is a MWEB:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}

\usetheme[progressbar=frametitle]{metropolis}
\usepackage{appendixnumberbeamer}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[scale=2]{ccicons}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{dateplot}

\usepackage{fancyvrb}%indent. code

\usepackage{color}%color words

\metroset{block=fill}%globally fill all blocks

\usepackage{xspace}
\newcommand{\themename}{\textbf{\textsc{metropolis}}\xspace}

\title{Funny title}
\subtitle{Funnier subtitle}
\date{\today}
\author{Funny author}
\institute{Not funny institute}
% \titlegraphic{\hfill\includegraphics[height=1.5cm]{logo.pdf}}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{frame}{Table of contents}
  \setbeamertemplate{section in toc}[sections numbered]
  \tableofcontents[hideallsubsections]
\end{frame}

\section{sec1}

\begin{frame}{frame1}

Citing stuff \cite{citethis}

\end{frame}

\appendix

\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]{References}

  \bibliography{demo}
  \bibliographystyle{abbrv}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

While my .bib file is:

```
@article{ citethis,
    author = "LaTeX Newbie",
     title = "As u can see, author name has been abbreviated and AlL tHeSe UppErCaSe LettErs haVe BeeN LowerCaseD",
    year = "2018",
    month = "November",
    url = "https://www.icannotfigurethis.out"
}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. It would be helpful if you composed a fully compilable [minimal working example with bibliography (MWEB)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that sets up the problem. While solving problems can be fun, setting them up is not. Then, those trying to help can simply cut and paste your MWE and get started on solving the problem.

Comment: Off-topic:  You don't need `\usepackage{color}` with beamer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To preserve the capitalisation of the title (or parts of it), you can wrap it in `{}`

The same technique can be used to enter a corporate author name, which does not consist of the usual name parts and thus should not be shorted to initials.

(See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/386066/36296 and [BibTeX loses capitals when creating .bbl file](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10772/bibtex-loses-capitals-when-creating-bbl-file) for further information)

```
@article{ citethis,
    author = "{Influx Development Team}",
     title = "{As u can see, author name has been abbreviated and AlL tHeSe UppErCaSe LettErs haVe BeeN LowerCaseD}",
    year = "2018",
    month = "November",
    url = "https://www.icannotfigurethis.out"
}
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, works like a charm. I did not know these effects of surrounding strings in { }. Thanks, you have teached me a big lesson :)

Comment: May I ask you how to immediately display the url too?

Comment: @LucaF For the url you either have to switch to a bibliography style which supports urls (have a look at the natbib package and its styles) or as a workaround `note={\url{https://www.icannotfigurethis.out}}`