# Reproduce chem-angew bibliography style

Tags: biblatex

I am trying to use the `chem-angew` bibliography style that is documented [here](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/biblatex-chem/biblatex-chem-angew.pdf). However the result I am getting is just not the same as the one in the documentation.
In the docs there are no further abbreviations in the bibliography (like `Vol` or `pp.`) whereas they do appear in my example. Does anybody know why that is and how I can fix this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=chem-angew]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{Sources.bib}
    @book{Paper,
        author = { Lenis-Rojas, O. A.  and Roma-Rodrigues, C. and  Fernandes, A. R.},
        title = {Inorganic Chemistry},
        year = {2017},
        volume = {56},
        pages = {7127-7144}
    }
\end{filecontents}

\bibliography{Sources}

\begin{document}
    In \cite{Paper} one can see stuff

    \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Example output]
So basically I want to stop biblatex from adding any extra abbreviations to my bibliography in order to achieve the result found in the docs of the `chem-angew` style

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to https://doi.org/10.1021/acs.inorgchem.7b00790 the source you want to cite is actually an `@article` and not a `@book`. The `.bib` entry should look roughly like

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=chem-angew]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{lenisrojas,
  author  = {Lenis-Rojas, Oscar A. and Roma-Rodrigues, Catarina
             and Fernandes, Alexandra R. and Marques, Fernanda
             and Pérez-Fernández, David and Guerra-Varela, Jorge
             and Sánchez, Laura and Vázquez-García, Digna
             and López-Torres, Margarita and Fernández, Alberto
             and Fernández, Jesús J.},
  title   = {Dinuclear RuII(bipy)2 Derivatives: Structural, Biological,
             and in Vivo Zebrafish Toxicity Evaluation},
  journal = {Inorganic Chemistry},
  volume  = {56},
  number  = {12},
  pages   = {7127-7144},
  year    = {2017},
  doi     = {10.1021/acs.inorgchem.7b00790},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
  In \cite{lenisrojas} one can see stuff

  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

which results in

[image: O. A. Lenis-Rojas, C. Roma-Rodrigues, A. R. Fernandes, F. Marques, D. Pérez-Fernández, J. Guerra-Varela, L. Sánchez, D. Vázquez-García, M. López-Torres, A. Fernández, J. J. Fernández, Inorganic Chemistry 2017, 56, 7127–7144.]

A closer look at the [`chem-angew` style docs](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex-contrib/biblatex-chem/biblatex-chem-angew.pdf) show that the style displays "Vol." for volumes of `@book`s and `@collection`s, but not for `@article`s. See for example [16], [22], [36] or as an example for `@inbook` and `@incollection` [18] and [21].

As an aside, I got the base `.bib` file from the ACS homepage and was pleasantly surprised that their exporter does not seem to commit the sins that [other exporters are too eager to commit](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/386053/35864). You may have to adjust the formatting of the `RuII(bipy)2` bit, though (granted, `chem-angew` won't print the title, but in case you need it later).