# How to treat 'and others' as infinite number of authors

Tags: biblatex

I have configured my bibliography to show

- all authors for up to 8 authors
- 3 authors et al. if there are more authors

This works mostly well, however there are edge cases where my bib entries have less than 8 authors followed by `and others`. Currently these are treated as if they have less than 8 authors, however I'd like that they would also be shown as 3 authors et al. (One can assume that all entries ending with `and others` have significantly more authors than 8, so it will never occur that bib entries ending with `and others` would have less than 8 authors in total.)*

To avoid problems with how to sort the `and others` in relation to real author names, I'd like to sort only by visible author names, this means up to 8 authors for small other papers, up to 3 names for long author lists.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}     
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}     
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage[
    style=authoryear,       
    maxbibnames=8,  
    minbibnames=3,  
    uniquelist=false,
]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{test.bib}
@ARTICLE{foo,
    author = {Ab, X. and Ah, X. and Ai, X. and An, X. and Ar, X. and Ar, X. and Ar, X. and Ar, X. and Ba, X. and others},
    year = 2018,
    title = {foo}
}

@ARTICLE{bar,
    author = {Ab, X. and Ah, X. and Ai, X. and An, X. and Ar, X. and Ar, X. and others},
    year = 2019,
    title = {bar}
}

@article{alice,
    author = {Ab, X. and Ah, X. and Ai, X. and An, X. and Ar, X. and Ar, X. and Ar, X. and Ar, X. and others},
    year = 2018,
    title = {alice} 
}
\end{filecontents*}

\addbibresource{test.bib}

\begin{document}

    \cite{alice} \cite{foo} \cite{bar}
    \printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

(*) I know that I could go though my long bib file and add at least 8 authors to each entry, but would require a lot of time and it feels pointless if these names will never be displayed

*EDIT*

What I have tried so far is to replace `and others` with `...and Ar, X. and others and others and others and others and others and others and others and others` to get more than 8 authors, but unfortunately additional `others` don't seem to count :(

Comment: Interesting question. For the `biblatex` side I could find an ugly hack by modifying the internal `\blx@namesetup` (there might be a more elegant way, though). But for the Biber side of things (sorting) things are more tricky.

Comment: @moewe If it would things easier, I'd also be fine with a solution that sorts all entries only by the first 3 or even first author only.

Comment: @moewe yes, in theory I know that they are bad, ADS unfortunately adds them and my regex foo is not strong enough to automatically get rid of them

Comment: @moewe I removed the {} from my MWE

Comment: Too bad. The ADS format is quite a headache (see also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/386053/35864). Then my comment should only be a warning for others reading this question.

Comment: @moewe Interesting question, there seems to be many things to learn. I will read it carefully.

Comment: If you always give at least three real authors before you write `and others` you can use Biber's sourcemaps to replace `and others` with eight fake names. Then truncation in the bibliography and sorting will be as expected. Obviously this does not work if you only have one or two names before an `and others` because that would cause a few of the fake authors to sneak in, furthermore this would be problematic with other `uniquelist` settings, so it is not really portable.

Comment: @moewe I have at least 3 real authors before `and others`, so this might work. Would it be possible to see and example? I'm not really familiar with how `sourcemaps` etc work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92362/discussion-between-moewe-and-user185617).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not aware of a nice solution to your problem that solves all issues at once.

Under the following two assumptions I can offer an ugly, but simple work-around

1. Whenever you use an explicit `and others` in a name field you must give at least three names (more specifically, you must give at least `minbibnames` names).
2. The `uniquelist` feature is turned off completely with `uniquelist=false` (this is already the case in your MWE).

We can then simply replace `and others` in a name field with a list of eight fake names via a Biber sourcemap. The assumptions 1 and 2 together with the `(min|max)names` settings then guarantee that the fake names are never seen or used for sorting. They are just there to make `biblatex` and Biber see enough names for truncation.

The assumptions and general set-up of your question may not always be satisfied, so I can not wholeheartedly recommend this approach for general use.

The `foreach=setnames`/`fieldsource=\regexp{$MAPLOOP}` combination applies the map to each name field known to Biber (`author`, `editor`, `translator`, ...). `match=\regexp{and\x{20}others\Z}` (maybe use `\s+` instead of `\x{20}`, or at least `\x{20}+`?) matches the string `and others` at the end of the field and replaces it with the eight fake names.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage[%
  style=authoryear,
  maxbibnames=8,
  minbibnames=3,
  uniquelist=false,
]{biblatex}

\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map[foreach=setnames]{
      \step[fieldsource=\regexp{$MAPLOOP}, match=\regexp{and\x{20}others\Z},
            replace={Fake One and Fake Two and Fake Three and Fake Four
                     and Fake Five and Fake Six and Fake Seven and Fake Eight}]
    }
  }
}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{foo,
  author = {Ab, X. and Ah, X. and Ai, X. and An, X. and Ar, X.
            and Ar, X. and Ar, X. and Ar, X. and Ba, X. and others},
  year   = 2018,
  title  = {foo},
}
@article{bar,
  author = {Ab, X. and Ah, X. and Ai, X. and An, X. and Ar, X.
            and Ar, X. and others},
  year   = 2019,
  title  = {bar},
}
@article{alice,
  author = {Ab, X. and Ah, X. and Ai, X. and An, X. and Ar, X.
            and Ar, X. and Ar, X. and Ar, X. and others},
  year   = 2018,
  title  = {alice},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
  \cite{alice,foo,bar}
  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Ab et al. 2018a; Ab et al. 2018b; Ab et al. 2019//References//Ab, X., X. Ah, X. Ai, et al. (2018a). “alice”. In://Ab, X., X. Ah, X. Ai, et al. (2018b). “foo”. In://Ab, X., X. Ah, X. Ai, et al. (2019). “bar”. In:]

---

Alternatively, the following hack

```
\makeatletter
\def\blx@namesetup#1#2#3{%
  \def\currentname{#3}%
  \c@listcount\@ne
  \c@listtotal\csname c@#3\endcsname
  \blx@namesetup@i{#3}%
  \iftoggle{abx@bool@more#3}% <- this test is new
    {\c@listtotal\@m}
    {}%
  \ifblank{#1}
    {\c@liststart\@ne}
    {\ifnum#1<\@ne
       \c@liststart\@ne
     \else
       \c@liststart#1\relax
     \fi}%
  \ifblank{#2}
    {\c@liststop\c@listtotal
     \ifnum\c@liststop>\c@maxnames
       \c@liststop\c@minnames
       \ifnum\c@uniquelist>\c@liststop
         \c@liststop\c@uniquelist
       \fi
     \fi}
    {\ifnum#2>\c@listtotal
       \c@liststop\c@listtotal
     \else
       \ifnum#2<\@ne
         \c@liststop\@ne
       \else
         \c@liststop#2\relax
       \fi
     \fi}%
  \blx@namecodes}
\makeatother
```

would cause `biblatex` to treat a name list with explicit `and others` as consisting of 1000 names (and hence truncating it as desired). But because this happens on the `biblatex` side only, it is too late for sorting (which is done by Biber). That means the order of the entries will be seemingly random, which is usually a bad idea. In the upcoming `biblatex`/Biber version that could be *partly* remedied by setting `maxsortnames` to a lower value (`3` I guess), but that would sort lists with between three and eight authors only by the first three names even though all names are displayed. So I can't really recommend this approach, either.

---

If you think the desired behaviour is useful for other people as well (because it is common practice in your field, required by a certain journal, ...) is useful, I'd like to urge you to open a feature request at https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues.

Comment: Thanks for this nice and informative answer!