# Error for \nocite command

Tags: biblatex

I am using Bibtex for references. Although I used the command `\nocite` before `\printbibliography` I still receive the error 'undefined control sequence'. 
I do not face same problem for command `\ref` or other commands for bibliography; this problem happens only for `\nocite`.

```
\usepackage[style=alphabetic]{biblatex}
\bibliography{bib}
\begin{document}
\nocite{Arnold89}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

where in bibtex file we have

```
@book {Arnold89,
    AUTHOR = {Arnol\cprime d, V. I.},
     TITLE = {Mathematical methods of classical mechanics},
    SERIES = {Graduate Texts in Mathematics},
    VOLUME = {60},
   EDITION = {Second},
      NOTE = {Translated from the Russian by K. Vogtmann and A. Weinstein},
 PUBLISHER = {Springer-Verlag, New York},
      YEAR = {1989},
     PAGES = {xvi+508},
      ISBN = {0-387-96890-3},
   MRCLASS = {58Fxx (70-02 70H05)},
  MRNUMBER = {997295},
       DOI = {10.1007/978-1-4757-2063-1},
       URL = {https://doi.org/10.1007/978-1-4757-2063-1},
}
```

and the exact error that I receive is 
"The compiler is having trouble understanding a command you have used. Check that the command is spelled correctly. If the command is part of a package, make sure you have included the package in your preamble using \usepackage{...}."

Comment: As always on the site please provide a self contained but minimal example that otehrs can copy and test as is. Here there are no document class, document env, no bib data etc.

Comment: \nocite` expects an actual argument, so perhaps you mean `\nocite{*}`.

Comment: I mean ```\nocite{document}```. It really does not matter; the problem remains for both ```\nocite{document}``` and ```\nocite{*}```.

Comment: Please show us the *full* error message you receive, if at all possible, please copy-and-paste the message directly from the `.log` file and do not rely on the possibly abridged version of the message shown by your editor. The message should indicate *which* command sequence is undefined - which would be a hige help in figuring out what is wrong here. As others have said, both `\cite{}` and `\nocite{}` will quite probably fail since they expect an existing cite key (which can not be empty with Biber) or `\nocite{*}`.

Comment: Note that `\bibliography{bib.bib}` is superfluous if you already have a corresponding `\addbibresource` line. In any case the command `\bibliography` expects the file name without extension, but `\addbibresource` expects the file name with extension. Finally, please consider showing us enough code to actually reproduce your error (we need the relevant `.bib` entries as well as a document starting with `\documentclass` and containing `\begin{document}...\end{document}`). See https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864 and https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864.

Comment: Any news here? Did you manage to make the code work? If not, can you please show us a complete example document and the *full* error message you get (see my last two comments above). In its current form this question can not be answered properly and if the important details are not added in due time I will vote to close this question as *unclear what you are asking*.

Comment: @moewe I edited the question with the exact error message and code you can compile.

Comment: @moewe I have corrected the extensions that you mentioned but the error still exists.

Comment: The quoted message is still not the *full* error message. I believe it is additional text added by Overleaf to give some context, but the red error message in the messages tab should contain even more details, in particular the actual output of the TeX engine, where you should find an indication *which* command is undefined. Though `\cprime` is a good guess for the undefined command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\cprime` is not defined by the packages you show. Either add a package that defines it or remove it from your bib file.

With `\cprime` removed and \usepackage{textcomp}:

[image]

```
@book {Arnold89,
    AUTHOR = {Arnol\textquotesingle d, V. I.},
     TITLE = {Mathematical methods of classical mechanics},
    SERIES = {Graduate Texts in Mathematics},
    VOLUME = {60},
   EDITION = {Second},
      NOTE = {Translated from the Russian by K. Vogtmann and A. Weinstein},
 PUBLISHER = {Springer-Verlag, New York},
      YEAR = {1989},
     PAGES = {xvi+508},
      ISBN = {0-387-96890-3},
   MRCLASS = {58Fxx (70-02 70H05)},
  MRNUMBER = {997295},
       DOI = {10.1007/978-1-4757-2063-1},
       URL = {https://doi.org/10.1007/978-1-4757-2063-1},
}
```

Comment: For keeping \cprime, what package I can add?

Comment: @shaha I would not keep it.

Comment: I'd just say `author = {Arnol'd, V. I.},`

Comment: Yes I got it I just need to change many tags like this in bibtex file

Comment: @shaha You might be interested in https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/386053/35864. This `\cprime` looks like a prime example of an auto-export with no regard for the real meaning of the character.