# Incomplete references in Revtex

Tags: revtex

I am using revtex4-2, with no particular bibliography style. But, I see that some of the references get listed with incomplete details. For instance, a bibtex entry

```
@article{lorenz2007repeated,
    title={Repeated averaging and bounded confidence-modeling, analysis and simulation of continuous opinion dynamics},
    author={Lorenz, Von Jan},
    year={2007},
    publisher={Citeseer}
}
```

appears as 
[image]

```
@article{kozma2008consensus,
  title={Consensus formation on adaptive networks},
  author={Kozma, Balazs and Barrat, Alain},
  journal=Phys. Rev. E},
  volume={77},
  number={1},
  pages={016102},
  year={2008},
  publisher={APS}
}
```

appears as [image]

I have tried using `\bibliographystyle{apsrev4-2}`, but that doesn't fix the issue.

Comment: There is a syntax error in `kozma2008consensus`: `journal=Phys. Rev. E},` is missing an opening brace, it should be `journal={Phys. Rev. E},`. An error like this can mean that BibTeX has to abandon any attempt to parse the entry and may lead to incomplete data.

Comment: Re the first entry: A short google search suggests the entry is not actually a journal `@article` (rule of thumb: It's only an `@article` if you can give a `journal`.), it appears to be a PhD thesis, in which case `@phdthesis` or `@thesis` is more appropriate. `@article`s never show the `publisher` field and your style does not appear to print `@article` titles, so that's what you get. You may also want to double check the name `author={Lorenz, Von Jan},`. As far as I can see the author is called `author={Lorenz, Jan},`. The "von" on the title page is German for "by".

Comment: Regarding the first one, I have copied the Bibtex entries from scholar as is. I didn't suspect that there could be something wrong with it. Regarding the second one, thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: It is always wise to double check `.bib` entries you obtain from tools such as Google Scholar. Sometimes the entries those tools export are of extremely low quality, sometimes even wrong. See the extensive list of problems with such entries at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/386053/35864 (and there are more problems ...).

Comment: That's helpful. Thank you.

Comment: I added the example `lorenz2007repeated` to https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/386054/35864. As it turns out the title field is also wrong.

Comment: @user206089 - Relying on the complete correctness of the bibliographic output produced by Google Scholar, other online search engines, and (yes!) even the publishers' own websites is -- sad but true -- rarely justified. Getting the entry type wrong and butchering one more names of authors and editors are among the more common mistakes. In addition, syntax errors such as (i) missing opening and closing curly braces to denote the argument of a bibliographic field and (ii) lack of a comma to denote the end of a bibliographic field, are unfortunately not all that uncommon.

Answer (score 2):

### `lorenz2007repeated`

The entry `lorenz2007repeated` is not an `@article`. A short Google search reveals that it is a PhD thesis.

```
@phdthesis{lorenz,
  author = {Jan Lorenz},
  title  = {Repeated Averaging and Bounded Confidence:
            Modeling, Analysis and Simulation of Continuous Opinion Dynamics},
  school = {Universität Bremen},
  year   = {2007},
}
```

Note the corrected `author` field (the author is called *Jan Lorenz* not "von Jan Lorenz"), the corrected `title` field ("`confidence-modeling`" seems to be a botched attempt to mark up the subtitle) and finally the corrected entry type `@phdthesis`.

The rule of thumb is: **If the entry doesn't have a `journal`, it is not an `@article`.**

Since Google Scholar did a particularly bad job at this entry, I added it to the list of horrors at [Software-generated bibliographic entries: common errors and other mistakes to check before use](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/386053/35864).

### `kozma2008consensus`

The entry `kozma2008consensus` is simply missing an opening brace in `journal=Phys. Rev. E},`. That syntax error means that BibTeX has to give up reading the entry at that point.

```
@article{kozma2008consensus,
  title     = {Consensus formation on adaptive networks},
  author    = {Kozma, Balazs and Barrat, Alain},
  journal   = {Phys. Rev. E},
  volume    = {77},
  number    = {1},
  pages     = {016102},
  year      = {2008},
  publisher = {APS}
}
```

Comment: +1 for adding this example to the "list of horrors" posting. :-)