# Should you use bibtex entries from the source?

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, best-practices

I wish to cite [this](https://arc.aiaa.org/doi/10.2514/6.2017-0423) article. A bibtex entry can be downloaded directly, which is as follows:

```
@inbook{Kleinhenz2017,
author = {Julie E. Kleinhenz and Aaron Paz},
title = {An {ISRU} propellant production system for a fully fueled {Mars} {Ascent} {Vehicle}},
booktitle = {10th Symposium on Space Resource Utilization},
chapter = {},
pages = {},
doi = {10.2514/6.2017-0423},
URL = {https://arc.aiaa.org/doi/abs/10.2514/6.2017-0423},
eprint = {https://arc.aiaa.org/doi/pdf/10.2514/6.2017-0423}
}
```

This makes use of the @inbook entry but does not provide any chapter nor pages. In the output, I still get chapters and pages which are just spaces (to be expected since this is a required field).

[image: Output]

Other articles cite this as

> [1](https://arc.aiaa.org/doi/10.2514/6.2017-0423) Kleinhenz J. E. and Paz A., “An ISRU Propellant Production System to Fully Fuel a Mars Ascent Vehicle,” 10th Symposium on Space Resource Utilization, AIAA Paper 2017-0423, Jan. 2017. https://doi.org/10.2514/6.2017-0423

which is the first reference from [this other article](https://arc.aiaa.org/doi/abs/10.2514/1.B37782).

I've tried using the @inproceedings entry,

```
@inproceedings{Kleinhenz2017,
title = {An {ISRU} propellant production system for a fully fueled {Mars} {Ascent} {Vehicle}},
author = {Kleinhenz, Julie E. and Paz, Aaron},
booktitle = {10th Symposium on Space Resource Utilization},
year = {2017},
month = {January},
doi = {10.2514/6.2017-0423},
series = {{AIAA 2017-0423}}
}
```

which yielded (ignore the number and the blue box)

[image: output2]

With this in mind, here are my questions:

1. Should you keep the bibtex entry provided by the source, or make your own?
2. What entry would best replicate the citation taken from [this other article](https://arc.aiaa.org/doi/abs/10.2514/1.B37782)?

Comment: External `bibtex` is unrealiable, generally. The `bibtex` provided via the `doi` is basically your second entry, which seems reasonable. The `inbook` category in the first version is totally improper use of that type. Your second question is much more about bibliography style than `.bib` file entry.

Comment: @AlanMunn I don't know if this was confusing, but the `inbook` category was the one provided by the `doi` `bibtex`. The second entry (`inproceedings`) was adapted by me.

Comment: I guess it depends on where you get the doi bibtex from. When I pasted the doi into BibDesk (a Mac bib manager) I get your `inproceedings` entry. When I use doi.org I get an `article` type.  So clearly they're using different sources. And your `inbook` is yet a third type, which just proves my first sentence. :)

Comment: I think the quality of the `bibtex` data depends on the source.  Some organizations or individuals are very careful to provide accurate data; this is more likely to be the case for sources that themselves use and depend on this tool and TeX.  It looks like the source for the citation you provide is not among them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `bibtex` format is quite specific to TeX, and there is no guarantee that external sources that provide `.bib` entries will use it correctly. This means that any externally gathered `bibtex` should be used with some suspicion.  The fact that it comes from "the source" isn't any sign of reliability, since it assumes that the source knows what well formed `bibtex` is like, which is often not true.

So what should you do in practice? Certainly getting `.bib` entries from the DOI is a good start, but I always vet them before using them to make sure they are correct.

To get a sense of the variability, here is the entry I get from pasting the DOI into BibDesk (with some BibDesk internal fields removed.)

```
@inproceedings{Kleinhenz_2017,
    author = {Julie E. Kleinhenz and Aaron Paz},
    booktitle = {10th Symposium on Space Resource Utilization},
    doi = {10.2514/6.2017-0423},
    month = {jan},
    publisher = {American Institute of Aeronautics and Astronautics},
    title = {An {ISRU} propellant production system for a fully fueled Mars Ascent Vehicle},
    url = {https://doi.org/10.2514%2F6.2017-0423},
    year = 2017,
    }
```

But here is the entry I get from doi.org:

Notice that the `doi.org` entry is `article` (which is incorrect), and it also fails to put `{...}` around the ISRU in the title. The BibDesk version does a much better job of getting things right.

```
@article{Kleinhenz_2017, 
  title={An ISRU propellant production system for a fully fueled Mars Ascent Vehicle}, 
  ISBN={9781624104541}, 
  url={http://dx.doi.org/10.2514/6.2017-0423}, 
  DOI={10.2514/6.2017-0423}, 
  journal={10th Symposium on Space Resource Utilization}, 
  publisher={American Institute of Aeronautics and Astronautics}, 
  author={Kleinhenz, Julie E. and Paz, Aaron}, 
  year={2017}, 
  month={Jan}}
```

And here is the version I get from Google Scholar:

```
@inproceedings{kleinhenz2017isru,
  title={An ISRU propellant production system for a fully fueled Mars Ascent Vehicle},
  author={Kleinhenz, Julie E and Paz, Aaron},
  booktitle={10th Symposium on Space Resource Utilization},
  pages={0423},
  year={2017}
}
```

For this particular entry, the BibDesk version is best (although since I use `biblatex` I would change the month to `1` from `jan`.)  The entry you got, which uses `inbook` is completely inappropriate for this type of entry, since that entry type is for chapters in books by a single author, a type that is very rarely used in practice.

For a comprehensive list of recurring problems with online bibtex entries see:

- [Software-generated bibliographic entries: common errors and other mistakes to check before use](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/386053/2693)

Comment: A number of issues with downloaded `.bib` entries can be found in https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/386053/35864.

Comment: @moewe Thanks! I had never seen that question. I've added a link to it in my answer.