# Biblatex: No "pp." in front of pages if pages field contains colon

Tags: biblatex

I have noticed that the output of biblatex for a entry of type `@inproceedings` is missing the "pp." in front of the pages if the `pages`-field of the entry is of the shape `x:1--x:15`. I strongly assume this is because the colon is detected as punctuation, but I could be wrong about this.
How can I make sure that I get the "pp."?

Example:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\begin{filecontents}{bibfile.bib}
@inproceedings{Test1,
    author    = {Author One},
    title     = {Papertitle},
    booktitle = {Proceedingstitle},
    year      = {2000},
    volume    = {1},
    series    = {Series},
    pages     = {1--5},
}
@inproceedings{Test2,
    author    = {Author Two},
    title     = {Another Papertitle},
    booktitle = {Another Proceedingstitle},
    year      = {2020},
    volume    = {2},
    series    = {Series},
    pages     = {3:1--3:15},
}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[style=alphabetic]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bibfile.bib}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

The output for `Test1` is expected and contains "pp.":

> Author One. “Papertitle”. In: Proceedingstitle. Vol. 1. Series. 2000, pp. 1–5.

The output for `Test2` is missing the "pp.":

> Author Two. “Another Papertitle”. In: Another Proceedingstitle. Vol. 2. Series. 2020, 3:1–3:15.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`biblatex` usually checks if something is a valid page/page range before it places "p."/"pp.". The colon is not among the default set of "numeric" characters and so will tell `biblatex` that we are not dealing with a page range.

We can tell `biblatex` to accept colons with

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage[style=alphabetic]{biblatex}

\DeclareNumChars*{:}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@inproceedings{Test1,
    author    = {Author One},
    title     = {Papertitle},
    booktitle = {Proceedingstitle},
    year      = {2000},
    volume    = {1},
    series    = {Series},
    pages     = {1--5},
}
@inproceedings{Test2,
    author    = {Author Two},
    title     = {Another Papertitle},
    booktitle = {Another Proceedingstitle},
    year      = {2020},
    volume    = {2},
    series    = {Series},
    pages     = {3:1--3:15},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Author One. “Papertitle”. In: Proceedingstitle. Vol. 1. Series. 2000, pp. 1–5. Author Two. “Another Papertitle”. In: Another Proceedingstitle. Vol. 2. Series. 2020, pp. 3:1–3:15.]

Often these two-part page numbers are supposed to tell us about an "article/paper number" and the number of pages of such a paper, in that case you can split the info into the `eid` field for the article/paper number and `pages` for the pure page range (which is often pointless in these cases unless you absolutely want to give an indication of the length of the paper).

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage[style=alphabetic]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@inproceedings{Test1,
    author    = {Author One},
    title     = {Papertitle},
    booktitle = {Proceedingstitle},
    year      = {2000},
    volume    = {1},
    series    = {Series},
    pages     = {1--5},
}
@inproceedings{Test2,
    author    = {Author Two},
    title     = {Another Papertitle},
    booktitle = {Another Proceedingstitle},
    year      = {2020},
    volume    = {2},
    series    = {Series},
    eid       = {3},
    pages     = {1-15},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Author Two. “Another Papertitle”. In: Another Proceedingstitle. Vol. 2. Series. 2020, 3, pp. 1–15.]

Comment: Many thanks, that works like a charm. I knew about the `eid` solution, but since the `.bib` file provided by the publisher doesn't use it, I didn't want to change that.

Comment: @LaReine More often than not publisher-generated `.bib` files are of bad quality (https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/386053/35864). In this particular instance it is understandable that `eid` was not used: Only `biblatex` supports it and publishers usually try to get something out that works for a wide range of BibTeX styles. You should feel absolutely no obligation to retain the `.bib` entry in the form exported by the publisher.