# Reference alignment problem with Overleaf

Tags: bibliographies, urls

I am using the LNCS template from overleaf for my seminar, and I have an alignment problem with my references. I use a `mybibliography.bib` file to store my exported references. The references are directly exported Citati. But the result shown in the picture is that there is always a alignment problem with the reference. :(

[image: Alignment problems]

And I used the splncs04 style included in the LNCS temple.

```
\bibliographystyle{splncs04}
\bibliography{mybibliography}
```

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: You should get an error from the missing math mode from using `4_1` in normal text. Use the `\url{...}` macro from the url or hyperref packages to set your urls and not normal text.

Comment: see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/386073/36296

Comment: Thks! Adding the hyperref package solves the problem!! :)

Comment: Glad to hear your problem is solved!