# Organize references in Latex by Mendeley

Tags: bibliographies

I used Google Scholar to export the citations in Latex but they are not written in a correct and homogeneous form for all the references. How can I use Mendeley to reorganize my references already made by Google Scholar?
I don't want to do this work manually because I have a lot of references.

Comment: Even if you switch to Mendeley, you'll still have to fix quite a lot of entries. Automatic tools very rarely get every detail right on their own.

Comment: The first is check if you can take the references from a better source (DOI, ISBN, ....) In my field references from PubMed are far better that those those obtained from  Google Scholar and other sources. If you have not alternatives, some programs as JabRef or KBibTeX can normalize some aspect of bad formatting, but no one can repair erroneus  or lacking information automatically. JabRef can show you a comparison of what you have with can it can retrieve from the  with DOI, but then is up to you decide what is better, field to field.

Comment: Maybe it is a long shot, but have you tried to use chatGTP to unify your reference format? Something like copy-pasting your reference list and asking it to write it in bibtex.

Comment: I think JabRef has a "clean up" function to make your entries more homogeneous and I suspect Zotero might also be capable of something like this. Not sure about Mendeley, though. My experience has been that automatically-generated `.bib` files are almost universally bad in some way or another (and with different degrees of badness): https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/386053/35864. They almost always require manual intervention and fixing.