# Adding Documents to my reference list from other .bib file

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, bibtex

I have a main reference .bib file where all my books and articles should be stored.
Now I have another .bib file in my overleaf folders in which some articles are, because I can download it in this format from my sources.

How can I add the information from the single .bib file with an article for example into my main .bib file?

Is there a possibility?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Hey @Mensch, thx for the warm welcome!

Comment: A `.bib` file is just a text file, so you can just open the other file and copy its contents and then paste it into the main `.bib` file. If you have the files on a computer you can easily copy from one `.bib` file to another using JabRef, for example, or you can append files to one another from the command line (Mac/Linux: `cat file1.bib >> main.bib`  Note the `>>` not `>` which will overwrite `main.bib`.

Comment: Oh okay. Well tbh I really thought it would not work with copy and paste. Thanks!

Comment: you can use more than one bib file. Simply add another \addbibresource to your file.

Comment: I wanted to not have a long list of .bib files in my .tex only one with the whole references in it. Is it in any other form possible to sum them up except copy paste?

Comment: @otto334 I gave you three options. You can easily script the command line version to add multiple files together.  Inside Overleaf, not really.

Comment: @otto334 I would use copy&paste, because if you download the bib file from your sources, you will likely have to fix the errors which are frequently in such automatically generated bib entries, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/386053/software-generated-bibliographic-entries-common-errors-and-other-mistakes-to-ch for a list of the most common errors

Comment: I agree with @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz on this point, I just couldn't find the question to link to :)  In that sense, it's probably easiest to use GUI bib file manager like JabRef (or Bibdesk if you have a Mac).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Summarizing all the comments:

- `.bib` files are just plain text files, so you can easily just cut and paste the contents of one file into another file using a regular editor (or the Overleaf editor if you're doing all this on Overleaf).
- It's not a problem to have more than one `.bib` file be loaded using `\addbibresource` with `biblatex`.
- If you have lots of small files containing individual `.bib` records, it's likely that these have been downloaded from the web using services like Google Scholar.  These types of automatically generated `.bib` entries are very likely full of errors, and you should check them carefully before actually using them for your work. See [Software-generated bibliographic entries: common errors and other mistakes to check before use](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/386053/software-generated-bibliographic-entries-common-errors-and-other-mistakes-to-ch)
- You can, however, easily append files to your master file using command line tools. For Mac/Linux, for example, you could simply use `cat file1.bib >> main.bib`.  Note the use of two `>>` not one `>` which will append to `main.bib` rather than overwrite it. This kind of command could easily be scripted.
- For easier management of your bib file, many people find it better to use a GUI program like Jabref (cross platform) or BibDesk (Mac only). This will allow you to easily correct missing/incorrect information in your file without having to worry about the syntax of the `.bib` file itself.