# Why don't the BibTeX files care about the spacing after the abbreviation-terminating periods?

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, bibtex, biber, horizontal-spacing

In the databases of DBLP, ACM, and Google, we can ask for a citation of a publication in the BibTeX format. Examples:

DBLP:

```
@article{DBLP:journals/ior/Dantzig02,
  author       = {George B. Dantzig},
  title        = {Linear Programming},
  journal      = {Oper. Res.},
  volume       = {50},
  number       = {1},
  pages        = {42--47},
  year         = {2002},
  url          = {https://doi.org/10.1287/opre.50.1.42.17798},
  doi          = {10.1287/OPRE.50.1.42.17798},
  timestamp    = {Tue, 31 Mar 2020 18:16:06 +0200},
  biburl       = {https://dblp.org/rec/journals/ior/Dantzig02.bib},
  bibsource    = {dblp computer science bibliography, https://dblp.org}
}
```

ACM:

```
@article{10.5555/2770781.2770788,
author = {Dantzig, George B.},
title = {Linear Programming},
year = {2002},
issue_date = {February 2002},
publisher = {INFORMS},
address = {Linthicum, MD, USA},
volume = {50},
number = {1},
issn = {0030-364X},
journal = {Oper. Res.},
month = {feb},
pages = {42–47},
numpages = {6},
keywords = {Professional: comments on}
}
```

(Yes, I know that `math={feb}` is wrong in biblatex, but that's not the point here.)

Google:

```
@book{1880vorlesungen,
  title={Vorlesungen {\"u}ber Geschichte der Mathematik},
  number={Bd. 1},
  series={Vorlesungen {\"u}ber Geschichte der Mathematik},
  url={https://books.google.de/books?id=qISWaqqWc_wC},
  year={1880},
  publisher={Teubner}
}
```

(Yes, though we know that the field `author` is missing here and that non-ASCII is not supported by bibtex, these are not the point here.)

In the first two, we see `Oper. Res.`, and in the third, we see `Bd. 1` (which is an abbreviation of German “Band 1”, which means “Volume 1” in English). As neither the language nor the after-period spacing in which these citations will be used are known in advance (hypothetically, a LaTeX class or language could use `\nonfrenchspacing`), we would surely write `Oper.\@ Res.` and `Bd.\@ 1` or `Oper.\ Res.` and `Bd.\ 1` for the widest applicability at least if we write them in LaTeX documents directly. However, when I ask the usual bibliographic Web services to export some citations in the BibTeX format, I never see any special care being paid to the period terminating an abbreviation. Why so? Is there, perhaps, a TeX-specific reason related to bibtex, biblatex, or biber (e.g., them messing with the space factor)? Or was I just unlucky so far?

Comment: Why-type questions regarding (lack of) forethought applied to various design choices can only be answered authoritatively by the author(s) of the respective pieces of software. Do you have reason to believe that these persons hang out on TeX.SE? My own view -- incidentally, I have no affiliation with Google, ACM, or DBLP -- is that if you rely blindly on whatever bibliography-related information these sites (along with Zotero, etc) produce, you have only yourself to blame for any mishaps. It's *your* publication, and it's *your* job to assure that its typography is appropriate.

Comment: Of course, it's not only typographic correctness you have to think about when you import bibliographic database stuff. Sometimes, there are more or less blatantly obvious errors of content as well. E.g., take the `1880vorlesungen` entry: it's missing the `author` field entirely! (It should be "Moritz Cantor", I believe...) I'd say that the missing `author` field is a far more serious issue than the lack of a spacing correction after "Bd.".

Comment: I've taken the liberty of deleting the `biblatex`, `biber`, and `bibtex` tags and replacing them with the `bibliographies` tag, as I believe your posting isn't specific to either of the first three tags. Feel free to revert.

Comment: Apart from what the BibTeX export functionality of these databases are doing, it does not seem very prevalent anywhere to use these spacing commands in `.bib` files. Take for example the files https://mirrors.ctan.org/biblio/bibtex/base/xampl.bib and https://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/examples/biblatex-examples.bib which are provided as official examples for BibTeX and BibLaTeX respectively. They use entries like `booktitle = "Proc. Fifteenth Annual ACM"` or `{J.~Amer. Math. Soc.}`, so sometimes `~` but never `\@` or `\ `.

Comment: Regarding the BibTeX output of these services also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/386053/software-generated-bibliographic-entries-common-errors-and-other-mistakes-to-ch is relevant.

Comment: @Mico Missing parts (such as `author=`) are per-entry. Not caring about space widths is common. Question improved.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Clarified concerning non-ASCII characters in the question. For the rest: I thought that, hypothetically, bibliography packages and classes might mess with sfcode such that it wouldn't matter.

Comment: @Marijn I see. Perhaps, should the official examples be improved?

Comment: Your tags seem to be mutually exclusive. Can you decide if you use biber or bibtex and then tag accordingly? (or use `bibliographies` if you have a non-specific question)

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I'm not sure: the question is specifically about `.bib` file syntax not generic bibliography issues, and that applies to bibtex and biblatex

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Consider reverting Mico's decision to add the bibliography tag. I've already re-added the tags [bibtex], [biblatex], and [biber] removed by him.

Answer (score 2):

As a general rule I'd say that you should keep tex markup in a bib database to a minimum, which simplifiies re-use of the data. It's already unfortunate that bibtex's lack of real support for non ascii letters means you need `{\"u}`.

As there are more or less never sentences in a bibliography, I'd say it is fine to use `.` unprotected with `\@` and leave it to the latex class to specify suitable spacing. Certainly the standard `article`/`book`/`report` classes all set the space factor of `.` so that you do not get a sentence space in these cases.

`classes.dtx` the source of the standard class documents:

```
% \begin{environment}{thebibliography}
%    The `thebibliography' environment executes the following
%    commands:
%
%    |\renewcommand{\newblock}{\hskip.11em \@plus.33em \@minus.07em}|\\
%      --- Defines the ``closed'' format, where the blocks (major units
%      of information) of an entry run together.
%
%    |\sloppy|  --- Used because it's rather hard to do line breaks in
%      bibliographies,
%
%    |\sfcode`\.=1000\relax| ---
%      Causes a `.' (period) not to produce an end-of-sentence space.
%
```

Comment: Is an instance of `thebibliography` environment generated by bibtex/biblatex/biber?

Comment: Moreover, why is the sfcode of only the period set? This is strange and probably counterintuitive. Consider the self-constructed example “J. Smith, Genderism: on Cis, Trans. Psych. Soc. 2024.” In `\frenchspacing`, it is unclear whether the title is *Genderism: on Cis* and the journal is *Trans. Psych. Soc.*, or whether the title is *Genderism: on Cis, Trans* and the journal is *Psych. Soc.* With `\sfcode` of the period only being 1000, we'd get `J. Smith, [more stretch]Genderism: on Cis, [more stretch]Trans. Psych. Soc. 2024.`, which unintentionally favors the first case.

Comment: In `\nonfrenchspacing` (i.e., ignoring the choice made in classes.dtx for thebibliography), we would get `J. Smith, [more stretch]Genderism: on Cis, [more stretch]Trans.   Psych.   Soc.   2024.`, which unintentionally favors the second case and wrongly separates Psych. and Soc.. :-(

Comment: @AlMa1r for your first comment yes, that's its main function to generate such an environment. The period only is set probably because Leslie Lamport was keeping code to a minimum in 1985 and didn't think he could afford more (although `\frenchspacing` would be less tokens and do more. it's been that way forever in latex). We can't really change the standard classes, but other classes can improve on the examples.

Comment: I see. By the way, llncs.cls, IEEEtran.cls, and elsarticle.cls do the same `\sfcode\`\.=1000` or `\sfcode\`\.\@m` directly or by loading article. Would it be better to say `\frenchspacing` instead or do you see any drawbacks? I could probably try to patch the environment locally. Or, perhaps, there is some fix-article.cls lying around where you put everything you developers consider necessary but not done by Lamport.

Comment: @AlMa1r not as far as I know, you should also check what biblatex is doing, there are less compatibility constraints there so more freedom to change things if they need changing