Biblatex: Overwrite 'pages' field with 'article-number' if 'pages' is empty
I want to overwrite the 'pages' field with the value of 'article-number', in case 'pages' is not defined at a BibItem.
What I tried
Together with GitHub CoPilot I came to the following approach, which somehow looks convincing, but does not give the expected result.
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,fleqn, headings=small]{scrartcl}  

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{filecontents}        

\usepackage[
    backend=biber,
    style=authoryear,
    sorting=nyt,
    maxbibnames=99
]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{demo.bib}
@article{witharticelnumber,
  AUTHOR = {Some Author},
  TITLE = {Article number is defined in bibtex},
  JOURNAL = {Sustainability},
  VOLUME = {14},
  YEAR = {2022},
  NUMBER = {22},
  ARTICLE-NUMBER = {14816}
}

@article{withpages,
  AUTHOR = {Other Author},
  TITLE = {Pages are defined in bibtex},
  JOURNAL = {Sustainability},
  VOLUME = {14},
  YEAR = {2022},
  NUMBER = {22},
  PAGES = {1234-4567}
}

@article{withpagesandnumber,
  AUTHOR = {My Carful Writer},
  TITLE = {Pages and article number are defined in bibtex},
  JOURNAL = {Sustainability},
  VOLUME = {14},
  YEAR = {2022},
  NUMBER = {22},
  PAGES = {1234-4567},
  ARTICLE-NUMBER = {14816}
}
\end{filecontents}
   


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\AtEveryBibitem{%
 \ifboolexpr{ test {\iffieldundef{pages}} and not test {\iffieldundef{article-number}}}
    {\savefield{pages}{article-number}}
    {}
}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\addbibresource{demo.bib} 

\begin{document}
\nocite{*} 

\printbibliography

\end{document}

What I get is:

What I want is:
To have the article number at the end of this citation.
Author, Some (2022). “Article number is defined in bibtex”. In: Sustainability 14.22, 14816.

Software used

pdfTeX 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.26 (TeX Live 2024)

biber version: 2.20


Thanks,
BerndGit

In the standard biblatex data model the field for the article number is called eid. A field called article-number is not recognised by  default. It is probably easiest to remap article-number to eid using a Biber source map. (Of course another option is to just start using eid in your .bib file. And going from article-number to eid should be just a simple search-and-replace job.)
If you then want to get rid of the eid in case there is a pages field, you can also have the sourc map do that for you.
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,fleqn, headings=small]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[
  backend=biber,
  style=authoryear,
  maxbibnames=99
]{biblatex}


\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map{
      \step[fieldsource=article-number,   fieldtarget=eid]
    }
    \map{
      \step[fieldsource=pages, final]
      \step[fieldset=eid, null]
    }
  }
}


\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{witharticelnumber,
  AUTHOR = {Some Author},
  TITLE = {Article number is defined in bibtex},
  JOURNAL = {Sustainability},
  VOLUME = {14},
  YEAR = {2022},
  NUMBER = {22},
  ARTICLE-NUMBER = {14816},
}
@article{withpages,
  AUTHOR = {Other Author},
  TITLE = {Pages are defined in bibtex},
  JOURNAL = {Sustainability},
  VOLUME = {14},
  YEAR = {2022},
  NUMBER = {22},
  PAGES = {1234-4567},
}
@article{withpagesandnumber,
  AUTHOR = {My Carful Writer},
  TITLE = {Pages and article number are defined in bibtex},
  JOURNAL = {Sustainability},
  VOLUME = {14},
  YEAR = {2022},
  NUMBER = {22},
  PAGES = {1234-4567},
  ARTICLE-NUMBER = {14816},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}

\printbibliography

\end{document}



Ok, thanks @moewe for your explaination.  I initially thought 'article-number' is a standard field as it was used in bibtex export on: https://www.mdpi.com/2071-1050/14/22/14816.   Since this is not the case, I think the most pragmatic way is to modify such entries manually and just use standard field like 'eid' from the beginning (as you proposed in your answer).

@BerndGit More often than not the data generated by .bib exporters does not follow general best practices (https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/386053/35864), so I wouldn't base any decision on them. To be fair, though, the closest thing we have to a standard BibTeX data model (i.e. list of supported types, fields and their meaning) just follows what the original BibTeX styles do. They were written in the 1980s and so just don't know about modern things like online-only publishing. So some additions like article numbers, URLs, DOI are ad-hoc and not uniformly supported across styles. ...

... biblatex joined the scene much later and is (only) slightly more centralised meaning that its data model contains more modern stuff and you can find out about what most styles support from reading the relevant sections in the biblatex manual I didn't realise this, but eid is slightly more widespread than I thought even in the BibTeX world. But it is by no means universal. I don't have any style installed on my machine that supports a field called article-number, though.

Thanks for additional info @moewe!
